# Appropriate place to ask questions related to cloud hosting provider specifics

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question to test my understanding of a cloud hosting provider's service (terms). Technically, this doesn't seem like a programming question...

So where on the Stack Exchange network should I ask this question?

Seems like this is a question that fellow programmers will best be able to answer, yet it's technically not related to programming...

Comment: Could you maybe edit your post with a short version of what you want to ask exactly?

Comment: Terms of service questions should be directed to the provider of those services.

Comment: Probably there is not. It would quickly become an advertising site.

Answer (score 5):

Such question will not be welcome on any site. At best it will turn into a recommendation question [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Specially the service and the terms under which the service is delivered will change at will, making answers obsolete at an incredible rate.

On top of that, the question is highly likely only applicable for your specific context, location and requirements. Your question (and their answers) will only be valuable to you, not to future visitors. That last group is the reason sites within the network thrive.

Your best bet is contacting the service providers directly and keeping track of your requirements versus their offerings. In big deals, bring your own lawyer.