# What exactly is a recommendation question?

Tags: discussion, questions, recommendation-questions

What exactly is a 'recommendation' question?

I understand and agree with avoiding questions on SO that garner answers which are basically opinions or preferences, such as "I like X" or "We use Y and it met our needs". These questions just lead to discussion and not answers.

However, I recently had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401466/create-a-pdf-from-a-pdf-in-php) closed on SO where I was looking for a PHP PDF library that supported a specific feature. Several people voted to close it, and referenced the now-closed ["What SO is not"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/stack-overflow-is) question.

To me, my question was not subjective or opinion-based; either a library supports this feature or it doesn't. Is it inappropriate to ask for a library that supports a specific feature?

There are *answers* to my question, but not necessarily only one correct one (though there might be, if at the present time there happens to be only one php pdf library that supports this feature). There certainly are **wrong** answers (namely, the pdf library that I'm currently using), which is mainly what I believe makes this question valid -- it doesn't lead to answers that are opinion-based. It doesn't matter how much you like a library, or how well you think it's written: if it doesn't support this feature, your answer is wrong.

So what exactly is a recommendation question?

**EDIT:** If I were to recast my question, here's how I would do it now (Shog9's recast doesn't really capture the question). I would more thoroughly describe my problem and what I've already done:

> **How can I load an existing pdf document and add pdf objects to it?**
>
> I have a website that generates PDFs. I'm using the ezPDF library, and
>   I can create a new PDF with it, add text, images, and graphics (such
>   as lines and shapes). However, a client has an existing PDF that they
>   want to use as a template, and then have the website add on the text,
>   graphics, and images. So I need to start from an existing PDF instead
>   of a blank sheet, so to speak.
>
> The library I'm currently using, ezPDF, does not support this. How could I support this functionality in PHP?

---

**EDIT**: User Bart made reference to the disallowed 'list'-type question. I looked over that question, and these are the qualities of the list-question in the top-rated answers:

> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite __?”

In my question, not every answer is equally valid. Not every php pdf library supports loading existing pdfs. For instance, the one I'm currently using doesn't.

> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use _ for _, what do you use?”

I didn't provide an answer along with my question. The library I'm currently using does not provide the functionality I need and I need to move to one that does.

> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

I do have an actual problem to be solved. I need to load an existing pdf as a template, and then add things to it programatically.

> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if __ happened?”

It's not open-ended or hypothetical. Any given library either has this feature or it doesn't.

> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “__ sucks, am I right?”

Not ranting. I never ventured any opinion about anything.

So, I don't see how this qualifies as a list question. Even though an answer might come in the form of a list ("These three libraries support the feature you need, take your pick."), that doesn't seem to meet the criteria of the list question as it was set out above.

People closed it on the grounds that it was a recommendation-type question anyways, or so they said in the comments.

Comment: I would say rather than a recommendation question you have asked a "list question". I.e. "What is the list of libraries that support X". [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question) contains some relevant information on those.

Comment: @Bart I don't think this qualified as a list question in the question you linked. See edit.

Comment: Regarding your edit: We prefer to focus on programming problems, not requests for links to external resources.  Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a good search engine, and it's not a proxy for doing your own routine research.

Comment: @RobertHarvey this makes sense and I can get behind this. Thanks, Robert :)

Comment: i just got a new idea for a stack clone...

Comment: i remember when a good search engine used to point to SO for these types of questions.  that's not 100% true.  it often points to old questions for old issues.  new ones not so much anymore.

Comment: "i just got a new idea for a stack clone": we are 2 ;) Stack Overflow staff has your own thinking about how programmers with questions must behave. It's highly fragmented (too many QA sites, while should be just one), and too many rules. Stack Overflow just exists because aren't alternatives with so many users. Of course there's good things like the karma/badges, but it's all. I just thinking to create a Stack Overflow clone with no rules at all, just one site to any type of questions (development, maths, etc). The main difficulty will be craw all the SO site and make some integration.

Comment: When google points you to a stack overflow question that was closed for being a recommendation question, this indicates there's a missed opportunity for this site as the de facto programming Q&A site.

Comment: I agree with @Taylor - it's maddening to Google something, find the perfect question on SO, and then find it closed as "asking to recommend a tool."  The process of programming *is* the process of getting familiar with tools and finding how to use them well.  SO should find a way to play to this need rather than trying to shut it down.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree that SO is not a substitute for doing your own searches & research. But I've come across problems where I want to do X and none of my searches and research yield any libraries, tools, etc., for doing X. And although I'm obviously biased, I think nearly all of these are problems lots of other programmers have, too. So if SO isn't a place "of last resort" for this sort of thing: anybody have any suggestion of a good place to ask? (Yes, this is a recommendation question. I could couch it in problem-oriented terms, but this comment is too long already.)

Comment: @Chris: There is http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com and http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com which, to my knowledge, are the only sites on the network that "officially" take recommendation questions.  They're able to do it because they are very specific about asking for criteria and turning away general "what is the best" questions, which are generally unanswerable.

Comment: Programmatically speaking, I think `Tools extends Ways`.

Comment: I think maybe a more important question is why isnt there a simple message referring people to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com if their question falls into that category. It would solve so many problems.

Comment: @alchemy It seems like not many people agree based on the results to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424880/in-the-automated-closing-message-should-it-mention-the-existence-of-alternative).

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Short answer? "Recommendation question" is shorthand for "you didn't describe a problem, you just asked for a list of things."

> #### create a pdf from a pdf in PHP?
>
> Is there a PDF library for PDF that can start with an existing PDF and
> add more things on to it? Currently I'm using ezPDF but that doesn't
> seem to support such functionality.

Add *what* to it? Pages? Annotations? Images? Password-protection? Presumably you *need* this library for something specific - can you be at least *slightly* more candid about what that is?

There are hundreds, maybe thousands of PDF libraries. If you're not *crystal clear* as to what you want, you're just going to get a bunch of answers from folks promoting their favorites, and you'll still be stuck testing each one to see if it actually meets your needs. And that's assuming you can even figure out how to use the ones that support this to insert the "things" you want.

> #### How can I add images and text to an existing PDF?
>
> I'm using ezPDF to load existing PDF documents, but I need to add images and text to them and ezPDF doesn't appear to support this.
>
> How can I load, modify, and create a new PDF from an existing one?

Not much different from your original, but focuses on the problem and not the solution.

### Pithy terms for a variety of questions

First, let's be clear: *all* questions are recommendation questions. You describe a problem, folks recommend solutions: potential fixes for a bug, possible algorithms, libraries, work-arounds, etc.

So when folks talk about "recommendation questions", they're actually talking about questions where it's difficult or impossible to know - as the answerer or a reader - whether one answer provides a better solution than another. [From the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask):

> To prevent your question from being flagged [and possibly removed](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion),
> **avoid** asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - ...

Two key points here: this guideline applies primarily to *overtly subjective* questions where there's insufficient criteria provided in the question to evaluate any given answer. These are popularity contests, spam-magnets, and [tend to become pathetically out-of-date](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/):

> Let’s say the question asker provided all that information. Fat
> chance, I know, but let’s pretend for a moment they did — and we were
> able to provide the *perfect, ideal shopping recommendation* to them.
> Even if that was the case, technology moves so rapidly that **the best
> shopping recommendations will be utterly obsolete within a year!**
> What’s the point of a bunch of labor intensive questions that provide
> only temporary benefit to a limited (some might say Too Localized)
> audience? There isn’t any.

The title of that blog post identifies another common short-hand term for these: **shopping questions.**

Now, there's a caveat: that blog post was written *specifically* to address the issues with hardware recommendations on Super User. Some of the problems don't apply in other contexts on other sites. But, a *lot* of them do. I've seen some *great*, well-researched answers on Stack Overflow library recommendation questions... That were completely useless because the libraries being evaluated had been superseded by new ones. This is a problem.

### Ask *how*, not *what*

For a library, you know what you want to accomplish, and you've presumed that finding a library that does it is the best solution - but without knowing if one even exists, that's an invalid assumption.

So just [ask *how* you should do what you want to do](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/#howtoask), and leave the library recommendations - if any - to the answerers.

- Maybe someone recommends a great library or framework and includes an example of how to use it.
- Maybe someone points out that there's a standard library routine to do what you want.
- Maybe someone writes a short bit of code that does it from scratch.
- Maybe it's impossible or unfeasible and someone tells you *that*.

But regardless, now you're asking a question that promotes *instructional* answers over rote recommendations, that promotes *learning* over popularity voting, the voice of experience over the voice of Google. You've invited answers that will be more useful to you, now, and others, tomorrow.

Good luck!

Comment: "Add what to it?" Any PDF object you can normally add -- images, text, graphics. I need to start with an existing pdf instead of a blank sheet.  Can't people just ask for clarification?

Comment: Yes, they could - and SHOULD. This is why I deleted that WSOiN question, because folks were linking to it in lieu of actually posting something useful. FWIW, I've also deleted about half of the comments on your SO question for this reason. I'm glad to see that halfer stepped up and gave you something useful. Thanks for bringing this up here - I hope this has helped.

Comment: It feels kind of redundant that I have to play dumb instead of cutting right to the chase and ask for what I need, "Hey guys, using PHP, how can I programmatically load an existing PDF and add images, text, and graphics to it?" Well, obviously I need a library, and I already happen to be using one. It sounds like I haven't done my homework, which isn't the case. And if I ask that question, probably one or more of the answers will be php pdf libraries that *don't* support pdf loading, like the one I'm already using. Is this really the right way to go about it?

Comment: You don't need to play dumb; pretty much everything you just said *is* the question: "I'm using ezPDF to load existing PDFs, but it doesn't allow me to modify them - how can I add images and text to an existing PDF (perhaps using a different library)?" Including the name of the library also helps. Note that one of the questions you were linked to is [hardly much more detailed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418945/tcpdf-start-with-existing-pdf) - but he mentions what he's already using, and what he wants to do (use existing PDFs as templates). You don't need to write a novel!

Comment: I wrote: "Currently I'm using ezPDF but that doesn't seem to support such functionality." I guess the terminology that was clear to me wasn't clear to everyone else. It can be tricky to guess the magic word ("template") that will work for most people :P

Comment: Yeah, it can - that's why we have "close as duplicate" (which I've now used on your question): we all tend to have slightly (or dramatically) different ways of asking the same questions. Note also that anyone voting to close your original could just as well have made a minor edit to it and avoided all the drama - another reason I hate the legacy of WSOiN.

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work, Shog9. It's part of what makes SO such a great and useful site. I'm happy to have my question closed as 'duplicate' :)

Comment: Actually, my takeaway from this is to more thoroughly describe my problem, not just ask for an answer. I see now that I didn't make it clear what exactly my problem was.

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry shog but the system doesn't work because you generally can't get a closed question reopened by changing from what to how. Users won't review their close votes after an edit and reopen reviewers almost never reopen a question

Comment: FWIW, I posted some statistics on how often stuff gets reopened a while back: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266709/how-often-are-closed-questions-re-opened/266844#266844

Comment: Even when following these guidelines, answers will very often become out-of-date for programming problems. Is that a problem? Should out-of-date questions/answers be removed? How is this kind of thing handled here on SO?

Comment: Answers can always be edited, answers can always be voted down, comments can be left, new answers can be posted... Obsolete answers are a problem, @Steven, but they don't have to be a crippling problem. Again, this is where answers that explain *how* (and questions that motivate such answers) are a thousand times more valuable than answers that simply state *what*. The PDF standard changes much more slowly than the market for PDF libraries.

Comment: @Shog9 I understand where you're coming from but sometimes the questions themselves will legitimately be about some problem with a certain version of a library (or at least the current version as at the time of posting). This could mean that a couple of years later a similar question and appears to be a duplicate, will not be because it requires a different answer (given the new version of a library).

Comment: The easiest way to deal with that is to simply reference the old question in the new one, @Steven.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm only just starting to think about the meta/model of SO.

Comment: I mean... what it actually means is "i feel like closing a question". The line between "recommendation" and "recommend a solution for this problem are fuzzy" and idiotic rule lawyers really like closing questions.

Comment: *What‘s just as important*, if not MORE important, imo is to disallow answers that only recommend a tool/library. When someone DOES want to know the answer to a programming problem (for one of many reasons), he does NOT ask for a library. But i have seen LOADS of questions i wanted to know who just got the ‚use this or that librar answer. You can link to a library on github that does exactly what you explain but EXPLAIN! And only because one person may be satisfied with such an answer does not mean every other person with that same question is (where we would be at the duplicate problem again)

Comment: They will close this question as one seeking recommendations.

Answer (score 33):

This question would be on-topic on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) (a StackExchange beta QA site).

Questions that are welcome:

- Libraries (with the tag `library`)
- IDEs, tools, standalone programs
- Web services (WSDL, REST APIs, etc)
- Web applications

Please note that rules are very strict over there:

- Questions are required to explain all requirements if fine details,
- Answers are required to describe how the app meets each requirement.
- Questions should be more about software features than about service terms, for instance [Open Source WYSIWYG HTML edition native component for Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/open-source-wysiwyg-html-edition-component-for-android) is on-topic but *"What CMIS library has good customer service"* would be off-topic.

Comment: This answer and Shog9's answer should be merged.

Comment: If a question meets all these strict requirements, then it should be allowed on stackoverflow instead of being evicted to yet another StackExchange site. It is a joke to find exactly the wanted answers in offtopic-questions after doing a google search.

Comment: The problem is no one that has the knowledge to answer the question is over there. I find infuriating that we have this community of people perfectly suited to answer those questions while not being allowed to.

Comment: Recommendation questions that can still be found on SO often are vague and have even vaguer answers. It is true that the SO community contains people who would be able to answer recommendation questions, but that's not a reason to force the SO community to read questions that the majority has decided are off-topic. The SR site is looking for answerers, please join! :-)