# "Not constructive" questions to bring diversity?

Tags: discussion

I've stumbled upon this question today which made me re-evaluate the "not constructive" approach of StackExchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438193/best-javascript-library-for-drag-and-drop

StackOverflow is being *pushed to first places* on Google searches nowadays and that personally helped me in countless situations when the only alternative seemed to be the sluggish and unfriendly Google Groups variant.

With the above-mentioned question closed as "not constructive", I found my answer and a diversity of other options, too.

So my question would be - perhaps it would be worthwhile re-evaluating the approach people take on such questions in order to:

1. ***save diversity of Internet***
2. ***outperform sluggish and outdated solutions such as Google Groups***
3. bring some love to developers :)

What you guys think?

Comment: "Not constructive" was an old close reason that doesn't even exist anymore. But today, this question would be closed as either opinon based or off topic: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Thanks for explaining stuff to me guys. I'm also equally sad to see that this kind of question is immediately seen as either a threat or something even worse, as I almost instantly got 2 minus votes without explanation and also coming from the irritated attitude of Cody Gray (who's answer is still constructive for me to answer the question though). Not to mention I have 1 rep here, so you can see I don't know how things go or know the background in this matter at all...

Comment: Oh, do I sound irritated?

Comment: @CodyGray sorry if I read the emotion from your answer incorrectly, it sounded that way when I started to read from "To the rest of your points, I don't actually know what you are arguing." :)

Comment: Downvotes on meta are used more to disagree with an idea, not as a reflection on the quality of your question. They don't affect your reputation at all, don't worry!

Comment: You're entirely misunderstanding the purpose of downvotes on meta. Besides the usual factors (research/clarity), downvotes indicate disagreement and upvotes agreement - thus, three people so far disagree with your proposal. I personally downvoted because (in order of importance) (1) I think questions in this format are not particularily useful for SO as many of the answers are outdated or even die due to link rot, (2) you lack some research as you don't seem to have a good overview of close reasons, and (3) your bullet points 1 and 2 are way too dramatic and don't really match the SO goal...

Comment: @l4mpi you are quite right, as I only visited Meta twice or 3 times in my life, I don't have a clue how it works - and I'm very glad you explained it to me. I feel much better and this all sounds much more reasonable now to me :)

Comment: Oh, I was afraid that's what you were referring to. It isn't irritation or condescension, I just honestly don't understand what you're proposing here. That we should allow any question? Or if not any question, what standards *should* we have? And I don't know what you mean by "I found my answer and a diversity of other options, too." What answer did you find? What are the other options?

Comment: Point taken Cody. I was basically opening the discussion to proposition of others but I see you have it all sorted out now. I apologise for the lack of research on my part, maybe I wouldn't need to raise this question if I did a bit of it. Also - what I meant was that the question itself brought quite a few options (some really outdated by now, yes) from which I found one that still works and was the answer to my problem I'm facing at the moment. So even though it's quite broad in answers, those answers were relevant to me during my search-for-solution phase.

Comment: Well, you can certainly open the discussion. I'm not trying to stop discussion. Sometimes on Meta I feel like people are too quick to accept answers. Sure, I like getting the checkmark, but the only way to *have* a discussion is for people to start posting answers. There is no pressure to agree with me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We no longer use the terminology "not constructive". It remains visible as a close reason for questions that were actually closed for that reason, back when it was an option. It wouldn't make sense to change it out for something else, and it wouldn't be fair to put words into the mouths of the original voters.

New questions like this would be closed for one of two reasons:

1. **Off Topic**
   Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question/254394#254394) and what has been done so far to solve it.
2. **Primarily Opinion-Based**
   Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

The word "best" in the title of that question you linked is a red-flag.

To the rest of your points, I don't actually know what you are arguing. I think we can all agree that Stack Overflow is one of the best resources on the Internet for programming answers. The way we maintain that position is by defining our scope narrowly. Stack Overflow, and its associated Q&A format, does not work as a recommendation engine. That has been tried, especially back in the early days, as you can tell from the question you dug up from 2009, but we've since learned better.

If that doesn't convince you, take a good long look at the answers to that question and consider whether any of them meet your three guidelines:

> 1. ***save diversity of Internet***
> 2. ***outperform sluggish and outdated solutions such as Google Groups***
> 3. bring some love to developers :)

Nothing about "hey, you should totally try jQuery" provides diversity to the Internet. Neither do largely link-only answers to libraries that may no longer even be maintained contribute to diversity or provide benefit to developers.

[Billy21's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6655494/366904) stands out as actually *contributing something worthwhile*. He provides expert experience, based on actual problems that he's faced, and explains how he solved them. This is good stuff, the type of stuff we like to see on Stack Overflow. Except that it is arguably *not an answer to the question being asked*. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, "not constructive" does not exist anymore. You can no longer close a question as "not constructive", today it is named "primarily opinion based".

P.O.B. questions tend to generate multiple answers, which are then voted upon by popularity, rather than by actual usefulness. This is discouraged because on Stack Exchange, the **best** answers are voted to the top, not the most **popular** (even though that still happens sometimes).