# Was the "primarily opinion based" close reason misused here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[I've posted a question about 5-digit plus years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826776/does-any-variant-of-sql-support-dates-far-in-the-future), specifically whether any variant/version of SQL supports years more than 4 digits

I think that the number of downvotes and close votes given for the question is a bit of an overreaction, given that I asked the question seriously and have given supporting evidence to why it matters, even today. But I digress.

My main issue is this: 3 of the close votes are for "primarily opinion based", but I don't see how it's primarily opinion based at all. I get that many viewers though it was a dumb question, but that doesn't make it opinion based. I asked if there were any variants of SQL that support future years and if not, why not (i.e. if there was an implementation reason). That does not seem opinion-based to me.

Update: I deleted the original question, both because of the level of downvotes and because it no longer reflected my actual use case. I appreciate the discussion and the effort went through by those who tried to improve it.

Comment: Given the current state of world politics, I think it's primarily opinion based whether anyone will even be alive in the year 10000. :D

Comment: That seems more like an indication that the comments are opinion-based. But even given that, I've already shown in the question an example (two actually) of how it matters even now - games about fictional worlds and applications like nuclear waste disposal planning.

Comment: It looks like a joke question.

Comment: Closely related: [Is it wrong to ask about the existence of a library?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261286), [Are questions like "does x support y yet" or "which x supports y today" ever okay?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145699)

Comment: You end the post with: "Whether any software people write today will make it that far is probably unlikely, but when it's easy to plan for, why not?"  This is asking for peoples' opinions outright.

Comment: _"If not, why not?"_ That's probably what got you "opinion-based" as you can be given any number of _opinions_ on why the creators didn't plan for 8,000 years in the future. I would've called it "recommendation" myself, after _serious_ consideration, as you are asking for any SQL variations that have this feature. That said, I could very well be incorrect on the "recommendation" call there, but I'm still figuring out the close reasons myself. (Don't have that privilege, just the flags.)

Comment: The better-fit close reason for what's probably your real question -- "Does any version support this?" -- would have been "questions asking for resources", but the rest of your post definitely lends itself to opinion-mongering discussion answers.

Comment: Regarding the "Whether any..." comment at the end, I agree that that is more of a comment. I only added it after the comments popped up to try and give some perspective to the question to anyone who came upon it afterward. I agree that a "resources" reason could be an appropriate close, but I still don't see how "why not" is by its very nature opinion-based. When someone says "Is 21 a prime number? Why or why not?" it doesn't make the question opinion-based.

Comment: The close dialog is limited, there is no "We don't want this programmer to be involved with our nuclear waste disposal problem" selection.  So SO users just pick something else.  I suspect you'll discover what the "meta effect" looks like.

Comment: I think your question, with some rewording, could be on-topic. The game example is valid (ie a game based on the far away future). If that is your intent, you should consider rewording it in a way that your end goal is obvious.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker can you purge the comments? They are obsolete after the edit. I thought it might be better to ask here rather than throw another flag on the pile :)

Comment: What practical programming issue are you facing that requires you to store year dates with more than four digits?

Comment: @Will The question was revised by Josh to imply that I am currently trying to store 5-digit year dates. This is not the case. What I was trying to do was plan ahead for 5-digit queries by allowing a query to have a 5-digit year in my regex. However, at least in mysql, a 5-digit year query will return ALL the rows, instead of none of the rows. This is the problem I was trying to solve. Allowing for 5-digit years in such a way that a search would resolve properly.

Comment: It's too bad the question was deleted; in it's edited form, I'm not sure that it was a *bad* question; it certainly felt answerable. Do you intend to repost a new version of it, similar to the latest edit?

Comment: Also - still curious what your use case was. Carrie suggested one possibility was futuristic dates for a sci-fi game. If you do repost it as a new question, **be sure to include your practical use**; it'll add credibility to the question.

Comment: @Lynn Call me selfish, but I'd rather not subtract 30 points from my rep *again*. lol. I'm going to just restrict inputs to 4-digit years and hope my software is fixed if it's still running in the future. If anyone else would still like to see an answer, they're welcome to post the question as they see fit. || My original use case was that I was trying to allow 4+-digit years for future maintainability, but because mysql truncates 4+-digit years, a search for 10150 becomes a search for 1015 (i.e. all dates), which is not something I wanted to allow.

Comment: Ahh, so then you were concerned with maintainability in the future vs. needing to currently support data that falls within that time range?

Comment: @CarrieKendall Yep, and you could easily make that argument that even if the OP's case doesn't make as much sense as the case that you presented (future game dates), the reality is that there *are valid cases out there*, and the question will be useful to future visitors (<- see what I did there?) Anyway, I digress..

Comment: You're planning already for 5-digit years?  This is why you got downvoted.  BRB, planning for 33bit integers caused by the universe's expansion over the next billion years.

Comment: @Will That's fair. But since I'm using PHP, the integer size will be handled by OS/hardware updates - I won't have to worry about the upgrade to 128-bit integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question was:

> Whether any software people write today will make it that far is probably unlikely, but when it's easy to plan for, why not?

"Why not?" is entirely opinion based. My reason for not implementing a 5 digit date piece of software is different from another person.

You also asked this:

> Are there any SQL variants/versions that support dates with a year greater than 4 digits?

That seems to be off topic because it's looking for a recommendation.

Comment: If I took that last line out of the question, would it be more acceptable? It wasn't meant as the main question. After all the main question is under a heading section called **Question**.

Comment: Whatever you put in your post is going to be fair game for answerers, @AmadeusDrZaius, regardless of how you labelled it, and then the answers devolve into a forum thread. Closure nips that in the bud so that it can be averted entirely.

Comment: @Josh Fair, but you should know that I added that last line *after* the majority of the comments (and close votes), precisely because people kept making what I see as a fallacy of the present.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: I've just made an edit to your question that I believe sidesteps both of the issues that Andy's pointed out. It's meant as a suggestion; please feel more than free to roll it back, but I hope you take a look at it and find it helpful. (It may also be too late for this particular instance of the question.)

Comment: @Andy I find your answer a bit misleading. While Josh is right that I shouldn't have included that in the post, it is very clear (both from the question inside the Question section and the actual question text "Does any variant of SQL support dates in the future?") that "Whether..." is not *the question*. Saying "Your question was: `insert here`" with what you've written above is not very accurate.

Comment: You have a "why not" under the Question section too. Your edits changed the question from a [recommendation](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27826776/1) question to an [recommendation/opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27826776/3) question. A more appropriate question may be something like "how do I get $database to support years with 5 or more digits. I've tried... and the following errors occur."

Comment: @Andy OK, fair enough. Re: Josh Thanks for the title change - it's better. I actually am asking this question earnestly btw, despite the belief of some people that it was a joke. I agree that the topic is a bit humorous, but I specifically tried not to inject any humor into the question.

Comment: @Josh I noticed that you also removed all of the background about the question. I don't know if that actually makes it better... including a little about why the question is relevant is important for it to be understood. The whole reason why the comments devolved like they did initially is because I *didn't* include any background. So I may want to revert part of your edit. It probably doesn't matter anyway though, since it's got 2 delete votes already. Harsh community, today.

Comment: @JoshCaswell's edit is on point. Your background section was noise and detracts from the actual question, IMHO. I suggest leaving it this way and waiting for answers.

Comment: @Carrie It's not quite right however, because I'm not trying to store 5-digit years. I'm trying to allow for searches for 5-digit years. I may just delete the question - I don't think it's going to get any useful answers now.

Comment: That sound like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Furthermore, you contradict the first sentence in this question.

Comment: Like I said, @AmadeusDrZaius, my edit was intended as a suggestion; please do as you see fit. The key points I hoped to make were: don't ask for "which version of X does Y", ask "how can I Y with X", and don't ask "why did D write X this way?" Good luck.

Comment: @Josh Thanks for the help - sorry if I came off callous. Just trying to communicate my original intentions clearly. I'll ask the question again in 9900 if I'm still alive.

Comment: Nope, no problem, @AmadeusDrZaius; I figured I might have missed _something_ when I edited.