# Is asking for how to store data in Google Cloud service on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm wanting to have a play around with some of the Google Cloud services (e.g App Engine), but I'm not sure what service I need to do what I want. Basically I want to store some data, that can sync to multiple across multiple Android devices. So the question would be.

Which Google Cloud service use to store data that I can sync to multiple Android devices?

Is this question fit for SO, or would it be better somewhere else?

Comment: That sounds like a recommendation question, which would be inappropriate. And not just for SO.

Comment: That's kinda what I was thinking, but I don't think this question could have multiple answer, I think it would have a clear cut answer. Does that still breach the rules?

Comment: It's not even a question. It's a statement of what you want. In any event, it doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that. I've just updated the question with an actually question, but I'll post it on a forum instead of on here, seems like a better fit.

Comment: I'm not an active chat user, but it could work there. I don't know what rooms will be useful(if any), so you'll have to do some research

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comment by [Bart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261584/is-this-question-fit-for-so#comment48285_261584) your question will be a recommendation request.

There is a specific close reason for these type of questions:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

In the answer on the linked meta post the blog post [QA is hard, let's go shopping](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/#howtoask) linked.

You can get recommendations from Stack Overflow if you disguise your question a bit.

For example:

> I use Google Sky Drive to store data that needs to be synced to a couple of Android devices.
>
> When I call `skydrive.store([data], no_limits);` only one device picks up the changes. I already installed the kitkat sync app but still no luck.
>
> Am I using skydrive correctly to sync data to multiple Android devices or am I using skydrive beyond its design limits?

Possible answers fix your problem, suggest to use iOS, promote Azure, or give solutions that will work by using one of the other data services in the Google portfolio.

Basically, create the smallest possible proof of concept and ask a question about that.

If you feel that isn't possible you can try a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=active) or use the support options from the service provider, in this case the [Google-appengine](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine) group, kindly provided by [Patrice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261584/is-this-question-fit-for-so/313079?noredirect=1#comment285968_313079)

Comment: As someone from the support team, I kinda feel I have to plug our Google Groups, which is WAY better suited to such requests: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine.