# Correctly moderating an 'is there a guide for using X' question

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts, moderation

I recently ran across this question when moderating the First Question section: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873400/swift-example-for-avaudiorecorder, where the user was asking "does anyone know of a beginner's tutorial for technology X in language Y".

- Should this be flagged as "low quality"?
- Is there a more appropriate way to restructure this type of question?
- Should this type of question be answered at all, as it can spread the idea that asking such question is okay?
- Is there an appropriate way to refer the user to an alternative venue for asking these questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a specific off-topic reason for such posts:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254394/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Examples are off-site resources.

You vote to close (or flag if you have < 3k reputation) such questions.

Comment: I didn't realize there were more options beyond the `it should be closed for another reason...` radio button.  I just assumed it would open a textbox the way `other (needs * moderator attention)` does.  So to prevent my future ignorance, is there a help section that describes when to use each flag?  The http://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging page is a little sparse.

Comment: @PhilipPittle: The [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page does describe each of those options (but not with much more information than that).

Comment: I had another question recently where the OP was asking for hardware recommendations for hosting VMs.  Is it correct that this was off topic for the same reason?  And do you know if it would be more appropriate for Power Users or another stack exchange site?

Comment: @PhilipPittle: Yes, asking for recommendations is specifically off-topic. Closing as 'external resources' or 'primary opinion based' is both fine. Recommendations are off-topic practically everywhere on the SE network.