# How often are closed questions re-opened?

Tags: discussion

Are there statistics for how often closed questions are re-opened? It seems that at any given moment, the close queue is around 10k-12k, but the re-open vote queue is almost always 0, so the percentage must be pretty low.

If that is the case, should anything be done to re-open questions more often? Many questions I see in the close queue are irredeemable, but many are simply missing details.

Comment: Even if a question is redeemable, that doesn't mean that the question author actually took the time to redeem it.

Comment: Agreed... more though, it seems to me that question authors almost never take the time to redeem it. Is this accurate?

Comment: Well, many don't.  Others try and fail.  Writing good questions is hard.

Comment: I'm desperately fighting the urge to say "rarely more than once"..

Comment: Actually what triggers a question for being reopened after someone edits it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I ran a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/210226/274076/test) to select distinct posts that have been closed. It gave me a result of ***355,438***.

I then ran a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/210227/test) to select distinct posts that have been reopened which gave me a result of ***14,437***.

So my calculator gives me a ***1 in 24.6*** (*4.17%*) chance of a question being reopened after it has been closed.

---

**EDIT :** @Braiam said

> Actually the proportion is off, since most close questions are
> deleted, hence not in the data dump.

I ran another [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/210273/missing-questions) looking for deleted questions. It gave me a result of ***1,169,980***.

Adding that result to the first result gives us 1,525,418 questions that are closed or deleted.

So that'd be a ***1 in 105.7*** *(0.95%)* chance of a question being reopened after it has been closed or deleted.

Not all questions that are deleted have been closed. Spam posts don't get closed, they get deleted. Questions can also be auto-deleted by the system without having been closed.

So to really answer your question, it's somewhere between  ***0.95%*** and ***4.17%*** chance of a question being reopened after it has been closed.

---

> should anything be done to re-open questions more often?

Anytime that the OP edits their question of a closed post, it gets sent to the reopen queue. Anytime that someone spots a closed question that they choose to vote to reopen, it goes to the reopen queue.

So I'd say more than likely, if a question is worth reopening it likely will be in *most* circumstances.

Comment: Actually the proportion is off, since most close questions are deleted, hence not in the data dump.

Comment: Kinda funny you did this given your name and all.

Comment: Also, it'd be awesome if you could interpolate between the two cases. Rather than just "closed" or "reopened", is there some way to show how many reopen votes they currently have? (full votes would mean reopened) That way we can figure out how likely it is for a question to gather *enough* votes for a reopen when it has at least *some* votes.

Comment: Your phrasing is off. There's nothing in your calculation that gives "the chance of a question being reopened", which implies odds of it happening. There is a 100% chance of a closed question being opened if it isn't a duplicate, it's edited to improve it, and the right people being the first to see it in the reopen queue (or see it as on hold and vote to reopen it on the spot). You're citing odds when you mean "average based on the data at this time". (Yes, I maybe am being a little pedantic, but this **is** a technical site. :-) )

Comment: +1, Thanks for the interesting data mining you did.

Comment: I'm really confused about how your [missing questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/210273/missing-questions) query works. It looks like it takes all questions, sorts them by id, then gets the row number of each record and assigns it to seqid. Then it joins that to the table containing all posts (questions and answers) using rownumber/seqId = posts.id, and counts any record where rownumber/seqId is null as being "deleted". I don't see how that gets you an accurate count of deleted questions. Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: @VotetoClose That will work for Users because all the user ids are sequential, so its easy to pick out the missing ids to find "deleted" users. But that won't work for Deleted Questions because the Posts table contains both Questions and Answers, and we can't just assume that every missing id number is a Question (although it is safe to assume that every missing Id is a Post, even if we can't tell if it's a Question or an Answer).

Comment: `Anytime that the OP edits their question of a closed post, it gets sent to the reopen queue` But what if the question is good and doesn't need any edit? like  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706696/which-if-construct-is-faster-statement-or-ternary-operator

Comment: @loli in that specific case the OP has enough rep to cast reopen vote which would send to reopen queue. If the OP didn't have enough or someone else didn't have enough rep to reopen they could start a meta post about the specific question or go to a chat room and ask about it and see what others think.

Answer (score 32):

[Vote to Close got reasonably close with his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266709/how-often-are-closed-questions-re-opened/266724#266724), in spite of not having access to good information on deleted posts.

Since this is something I check fairly regularly, I'll flesh this out a bit more. First, here are the all-time stats:

```
Closed Closed then Edited Closed then Reopened Closed then Edited then Reopened 
------ ------------------ -------------------- -------------------------------- 
903399 130538             19264                11139
```

So, just a bit over 2%, with edits bumping that up to a bit over 8%.

Looking at just questions closed in the past 365 days, we get:

```
Closed Closed then Edited Closed then Reopened Closed then Edited then Reopened 
------ ------------------ -------------------- -------------------------------- 
371781 46545              8648                 6308
```

Which is still about 2%, but up to 13% for posts that get edited. This gets a bit more interesting when you break it down by close reason:

```
Name                       Closed Closed then Edited Closed then Reopened Closed then Edited then Reopened 
-------------------------- ------ ------------------ -------------------- -------------------------------- 
duplicate                  67790  6670               1693                 695                              
off-topic                  170046 18189              3762                 2991                             
primarily opinion-based    19834  2355               319                  163                              
too broad                  42989  6312               741                  561                              
unclear what you're asking 71121  13019              2133                 1898
```

Replacing that with %s and you get:

```
Name                       Closed then Edited Closed then Reopened Closed then Edited then Reopened 
-------------------------- ------------------ -------------------- -------------------------------- 
duplicate                  9.8                2.5                  10.4                             
off-topic                  10.7               2.2                  16.4                             
primarily opinion-based    11.9               1.6                  6.9                              
too broad                  14.7               1.7                  8.9                              
unclear what you're asking 18.3               3                    14.6
```

So yeah; a lot of stuff stays closed, but the best way to increase the chance of a question being reopened is to edit it. Funneling these questions into reopen *has* helped, although there's still more we could do to improve that.

Comment: It's too bad we can't re-cast the close reasons once it's been closed but edited. Essentially, the close reason is what happens mostly at the first revision (although there can be some edits before the final close vote is cast). It's always odd to see question closed for the wrong reason, but it seems even worse if the question has been edited and improved with more details. This could be a reason why "unclear" seems higher than the others in these stats. (Perhaps we could also withdraw close votes even once the question has been closed if it has been edited, thereby reopening it.)

Comment: I know the "closed" and the "in the close queue" count aren't necessarily the same, but if "closed then edited" is about 13% of the "closed", why do I have 10.3k questions in my close queue and just 1 question in my re-open queue?

Comment: Imagine you were the only reviewer, @Bruno. You're able to do 20 reviews per queue per day. One queue gets 10 items, and you review all of them. The other queue gets 77 items... You're gonna have items you can't review, and it's gonna get bigger every day.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you point here. I'm just surprised that there are so few questions in the re-open queue in comparison to the close queue, if closed edited questions are meant to make it automatically there. Say 10% of the questions in my close queue are closed, that makes about 1000 questions. Assuming questions are spread in equal quantities and roughly uniformly between users, if 13% of those closed questions are edited, I'd expect to see roughly 130 questions in my re-open queue. Yet there's only ever 0 or 1...

Comment: I know it's more complicated than that, but the count ratio between counts in my re-open queue over count in my close queue (1/10000) seems very surprising if you consider that 13% of the closed questions overall should enter the global re-open queue.

Comment: Good to know, so if it's unclear what you are asking, then it definitely benefits you to edit since that's the crux of the problem. Interesting that duplicate questions that are edited are the third highest to be reopened after editing. I would have thought they would have been lower.

Comment: If it's not too difficult, would you run the stats against Programmers as well please?  Using VTC's queries I get 8783 closed and 743 reopened for ~8.5% reopen rate.  But I know Progs is fairly quick to delete off questions that can't be salvaged.

Comment: Post this request on progse's meta please, @glen. I'll see what I can do. Link to this answer in your request.

Comment: Here's the [MP.SE version of this question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6789/53019).  Thanks for taking a look at it!

Comment: I wonder how many of those that were closed (for good reason) and reopened (after editing) actually have an accepted answer? I would think that by the time the question is closed, edited and reopened it would find itself on the 3rd+ page and unlikely to receive any attention. Perhaps the asker would be better to let it go and use the experience to post a better question.

Comment: @Bruno: You're not thinking at the margin. It's not about the queue length, but about how many enter vs how many leave each day. There are (at present) about a third as many close voters at 40/day as there are possible reviews per day; the other two thirds get aged out of the queue after a few days and probably never get closed. 13% of 1/3 means that, even at 20/day, there's easily enough reviewers to handle almost four times as many reviews as there actually are. So even if there was a 10000 item queue, it would only take a few weeks to burn down to 0 and stay there.

Answer (score 3):

I think we're all allocated different questions in our respective re-open queues. Looking at the [overall history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history), there is a little bit of activity overall (not very much), but for that doesn't mean it translates into each of us seeing those questions.

I assume we're allocated which questions to review more or less randomly.

The problem with this mechanism is that you need to be proactive to re-open a question. In doubt, people leave closed.

It's always easier to find 5 non-experts on any field, who will not understand the question to leave it as "unclear", or not get the subtlety of a not-quite-duplicate, than it is to find someone with a bit more expertise who will have a better understanding about these issues, and understand *why* the question should be re-opened.

That's why in practice, once a question is closed, it is very hard to get it re-opened.

Comment: I sometimes visit the reopen queue and unfortunately "Leave Closed" seems to be the right choice more regularly than "Reopen". Of course mistakes happen, but I see far more questions that should be closed but are open than ones that are closed but should be reopened. The former poison the whole site and community, while the latter is only an inconvience for a single person (which is unfortunate and should be avoided of course).

Comment: @kapa But if SO really is about the [long tail programming question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) (and also considering that some high-rep answers complain they're always answering the same type of easy questions), it's those questions that are harder and unclear to most that need to be rescued. The majority of close voters don't necessarily get that difference. (I don't necessarily agree with that blog entry, by the way, since SO really isn't adapted for CW or collaborative authorship, but that's a different problem.)

Comment: I don't think SO wants to rescue anyone. SO provides answers, not hand-holding. If you don't understand the answers, SO cannot help (think about an university as an analogy). Also, 90% (or more) of those reoccuring questions happen not because the OP found the previous questions and could not understand, but because the OP made no effort at all to find them. I close a lot of dupes, and most of the time the OP is actually helped by the dupe.

Comment: @kapa I wasn't talking about rescuing people, I was talking about re-opening more obscure questions than are considered unclear (or almost duplicates) by most, but for which more expert users can see where the subtly is.

Comment: I understand now. I have not seen much of these questions closed yet though :).

Answer (score -3):

There's nothing inherently valuable about a question such that we should prioritize re-opening.  If someone wants to invest their own time in it (such as the OP) to redeem it, then great.  Otherwise, if the question and its answer are valuable to other people, it will be asked again, hopefully better.

Comment: Not sure what your point about prioritising is. This was mostly about getting questions re-opened at all after improvements (or counteracting unnecessary closures). There's no notion of "priority" in there.

Answer (score -27):

Practically never. In my 5+ years of StackOverflow, I've spotted [countless questions that have been mistakenly closed](https://pinboard.in/search/u:dandv?query=stackoverflow+closed) by moderators simply unfamiliar with the topic. How many have I managed to get reopened? Probably two.

Comment: I followed that link. You call people idiots and morons for closing questions that are clearly meant to be closed according to the site's rules. Are you fighting for the fun of fighting? You are certainly not fighting for achieving any results, because you are harassing the policemen instead of the people who make the rules. I don't really understand people like you... what is your goal, honestly?

Comment: Oh, thank you for the list of questions that should probably still be closed.

Comment: @animuson, it was wrong to delete [this popular informative question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498308/how-to-choose-between-zombie-js-and-phantomjs-for-automated-web-testing) unilaterally.  It should have just been locked.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I see absolutely nothing of significant value in that question.

Comment: @animuson, well obviously, those interested in those technologies found it valuable enough.

Comment: Wanna actually make a difference? [Edit.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266709/how-often-are-closed-questions-re-opened/266844#266844)

Comment: @animuson: it's "policemen" like you that not just [drive users away from StackExchange, but make them actively hate it](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/).

Comment: @Dan Most of the users that hate Stack Exchange are the ones that are too lazy to formulate good questions and answers and then don't care enough to understand why those questions and answers weren't good, kind of like the person in that blog. The entire thing is based on a question which is terrible by Stack Overflow's standards. But your strategy is good. Going around calling people stupid Nazi a**h*les is definitely the *best* way to go about getting questions reopened.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Driving away people is not really a problem. In fact, SO is suffering because of the masses who are unable/unwilling to understand the goals.