# Are novice questions being put on hold too quickly?

Tags: discussion

There have been a couple of questions recently that have been put On Hold (too broad) within a short time of them having been asked.  In their original form the questions do indeed fail to meet the SO standard.  However, there is a chance that they could have been salvaged, at least from the point of view of helping the author.

It appears to me that this happens particularly when:

1. The author is not a native English speaker.
2. The author is (relatively) inexperienced in the technology they're asking about.

In both of these questions [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27531288/3581917) and [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27544519/3581917), I was preparing an answer which, if accepted by the author, would have allowed me to suggest edits to the question that might have made it salvageable.  Since the questions are both now On Hold, I'm limited to comments or chat.

Have these questions been put on hold too soon?  Or are they really beyond salvage?

It's true that there are a very large number of poor questions.  There are also a significant number of questions that may never be useful to anyone other than the OP.  The examples given above almost certainly fall into the latter category, but does that mean they shouldn't be answered and tidied up to meet the SO standards if they can be?

**Edit**

The answers below all accurately and reasonably explain the reason why questions are put On Hold.  I understand them and have no debate: that's how the site works, and mostly it works well.  However, none of them address my question which realtes to how quickly it happens.

I'm not one of the FGTW contributors.  Nor do I spend much time here (I have too much work of my own to do).  So when I do contribute I mostly try to put a bit of time into answering one or two questions well.  This usually involves firing up an IDE, putting some code in and (at least) making sure it builds, before writing a little text to explain the code and formatting the answer so it looks pretty.

If the question has been put on hold by the time I've done this, then there is no option to suggest an answer and the time I've put into coming up with one is wasted unless the OP edits the question.

I think that maybe the fault is mine and I'm making a cardinal engeering error and assuming I know what the OP is asking and going off writing code to solve the wrong problem.  Putting the question On Hold quickly helps to prevent that by forcing the OP to clarify before I waste my time answering the wrong question.

Comment: Putting questions on hold is done precisely so the author has a chance to fix them.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yes, I understand that.  However, in some instances, such as those I've specified in the question, the author may not understand or have sufficient knowledge of the subject to be able to do so.  In which case, having an answer could help; or provide the answerer with the opportunity to do so on behalf of the author.

Comment: My answer goes into more detail, but essentially if the question hasn't included enough information to solve the issue, it is not useful to others. If it's not useful to others, we don't want it on the site.

Comment: Well, step up to the plate and edit the question so it becomes answerable.  Assuming that you know what it is asking the first place.  If you sputter "but that's too much work" then, sure, it is.  You can't really expect anybody else not the feel the same way either.  There already is a massive amount of work done to keep this site useful that doesn't have anything to do with providing answers.  Too much.

Comment: One problem is that it's often difficult to differentiate between an unskilled enthusiast and a deadbeat student who just wants work done for them for free.   SO is a site for professional and enthusiast programmers and, as such, a certain level of skill might well be assumed to exist for posters.  Questions showing, for example, a gross lack of understanding of language syntax, are not helpful to SO and should be closed.

Comment: @MartinJames Go ahead and look for that in the close reasons. You won't find it. :-)

Comment: @HansPassant I'm happy to do that and will take a look at the question that has been answered in the comments since being put on hold to see if it can be edited to reflect the real issue better to turn it into a decent question.

Comment: @gnat Yup, you're probably right. Not sure how I missed it (or the one it's duped against), maybe the word 'novice' in my title / search string skewed the results.

Comment: If I see any more "debug my tic tac toe" questions that show no research I think I'm going to go postal! There are novice questions that are valid but faaar too many of them fail to meet site requirements, show no research, and are duplicates. This site is already a brilliant resource, but we *have to keep the quality up and the noise down*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point of putting questions on hold is two fold:

1. To give the OP the opportunity (and direction) to fix their question.
2. To ensure that questions that are answered are useful to others.

The close reasons we use are intentional: Their purpose is to ensure that any question that is not useful to others is closed.

If we closed questions after they were answered, we've (in effect) defeated half the purpose of closing a question: It's been answered, so the OP has no incentive to improve it for it to be useful to others!

The effect of closing is to give the OP time to salvage their question. If a question is truly unsalvagable, it should be deleted.  That comes later, after the OP has been given sufficient time to fix the problem with their question.

The other half is to ready it for deletion -- which if it doesn't happen in 60 days, doesn't matter for reputation anyway.

Closed questions are also (probably) taken into account by the question ban algorithm. A high number of closed question indicates the user does not understand the site. It would not be helpful to them or to the rest of the community to let them continue asking questions if they do not understand the site's purpose.

In short, if you have an answer to a question that is closed, the best thing you can do is to *edit the question* to include the information needed to re-open it (if you can). If you can't, then you can let the OP know what they need to do in order for it to be re-opened.

Or you can get together a re-open vote posse and sit around in chat and re-open questions.  [It works for the close vote people](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

In your first example, The OP has not given us valid inputs and outputs to let us know what they expect.  In the second, the OP's inputs and outputs make no sense.  It was closed as 'too broad', but it should have been closed as 'unclear what you're asking'.  I've gone ahead and left a comment and made the close vote change to the appropriate reason.

Comment: Thank you.  Your comment on the second worked and the OP editted the question, making things much clearer.  An answer to the first has been found and supplied in the comments secion (a localisation issue).

Answer (score 7):

> Have these questions been put on hold too soon? Or are they really beyond salvage?

If a question is beyond salvage, then it should be put on hold. **But if a question is put on hold, it does not mean it is beyond salvage.** Putting the question on hold gives the opportunity to the author to edit their question until it is edited into shape. Otherwise, the OP risks getting answers that don't actually solve the problem the OP means to solve. The answerers answer on the basis of a misleading question, and then the OP has to tell each answerer that their answer is not hitting the mark. I've seen it happen time after time. It is just aggravating to all involved. Everybody is wasting their time and the OP ends up annoying those people who could help.

Comment: If only those posters would follow the advise in the large grey box with the big title. I'd guesstimate that about 90% of questions-put-in-the-fridge are abandoned or (less often, but much worse) just asked again.

Comment: @Jongware [that's about 87%](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266844/839601 "per my reading of analysis here")

Answer (score 4):

They are salvageable. Hence, the last line in the dialog appearing below the 'on hold' message:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment.

That is what OP needs to do. Then it can be reopened. (Closed / on hold questions that are edited are put in the reopen queue to review them).

Comment: Certainly, Patrick. But I suspect that lots of new posters (especially first-timers) get discouraged when their question is put on hold, and perhaps they take it as a personal attack. (I guess such people haven't taken the tour, or at least, haven't read enough of the Help material to understand how these communities work.) So when you ask them in a comment for the crucial information that would allow you to fix up their question and answer it, it's quite common to not get a reply. I wish there were a simple solution to this problem, but I suspect that there isn't.

Comment: I think they get discouraged more by answers that do a guess to the problem, and then find out it was all wrong. OP should make himself clear first, then we will answer.

Comment: Fair point. I'm not suggesting that such questions not be put on hold, but maybe the accompanying message could be written in a way that's less intimidating so that they realise that we _do_ really want to help them. I sometimes say in my comments requesting crucial information to on-hold questions things like "help us to help you" but I often get the feeling that the OP has moved on and hasn't even read my comment.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Then suggest a rewording, but I warn you, it has tried before. Make sure it really covers it all.