# Do improved questions actually get re-opened after they've been put on hold?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, vote-to-reopen, on-hold

Take the following (now closed and deleted) question as example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801813/how-can-i-generate-circles-with-random-thickness-and-radius-in-matlab?noredirect=1#comment53450342_32801813

This question was put on hold almost immediately after its creation because a new user did not provide sufficient background information. A high rep user left a sarcastic comment and left the newcomer with an even bigger dazzle. Other than this being a very rude gesture as a way of welcoming someone to what is referred to as a community, the user eventually apologized and updated his question with all its research effort. The question was never considered to be re-opened, and it seemed like those who close-voted never looked at the question again. Aren't close-voters supposed to take responsibilities for their actions, or do they? I also did a small search to find some kind of button to flag the question as appropriate, but it seemed not to be there. This left me with the conclusion that close-voters ought to be aware of the responsibility involved.

Because the question was still on hold, I provided an answer in the comments, simply because it was not possible to provide it as an answer. I planned to move it to the answer section after the question would be re-opened. A few days later, the post was closed, and now it is deleted, which left me baffled.

I'm wondering if this is a one-time occurrence, or if it happens more often that questions put on hold never get a second look.

Note that this question is a general one, and not specifically addressed to above anecdote. The anecdote was just a motive for me to ask this question. This question is different from the proposed duplicate posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266709/how-often-are-closed-questions-re-opened), because that question considers the general case of all closed questions, whereas I'm considering the (in my opinion more valuable) specific general case of closed questions that have been edited by the OP after it has been put on hold (with an attempt of the OP to improve the question). There is a significant difference because most newcomers don't attempt to improve their question.

Comment: If a question that is on hold or closed gets edited, it automatically goes to a "reopen" queue where people can decide if it's good enough to be reopened or not. I'd love to help you more, but I don't have enough rep to see the (now deleted) post. Also you have to realize with the CONSTANT flood of crap being sent here, people have better things to do than re-visit stuff they've voted to close. It's sad, but do consider that, when a post gets on hold or closed, more often than not the Original Poster does NOTHING to edit it, so it's not worth to revisit posts for no reason

Comment: "Now deleted" there's your problem.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Could you elaborate?

Comment: *"the user eventually apologized and updated his question with all its research effort"* - you realise that's still not actually an appropriate question, right? As a result, nobody reviewing it ever voted to reopen.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266709/how-often-are-closed-questions-re-opened

Comment: It can't be reopened if it's deleted.  That's what deleted means. It's gone to the general public.  So first the user would have to undelete the question.  Even then, a user can't undelete a question that they didn't delete themselves.

Comment: @JJMDriessen Regarding your claim that your question is not a duplicate, [Shog's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266844/) on that other question deals with the kind of details you are after.

Comment: This question has been downvoted and marked as duplicate, but I'm not sure why.  I found the question thoughtful and the discussion informative.  Is there another question on meta regarding how the on hold queue works that does it better?

Answer (score 3):

> The question was never considered to be re-opened, and it seemed like
>   those who close-voted never looked at the question again. Aren't
>   close-voters supposed to take responsibilities for their actions, or
>   do they?

Close voters aren't required to revisit every question they've ever cast a vote on to see if it has been improved (thank goodness!) When the question is edited it is automatically pushed to the reopen queue, where other users can vote to reopen if they think it has been improved sufficiently to now be acceptable. **This question hadn't been** - even with the OP's eventual edit it was not appropriate for SO.

> I'm wondering if this is a one-time occurrence, or if it happens more
>   often that questions put on hold never get a second look.

That's not what happens at all - they do get a second look, but that by no means guarantees they will be reopened.

> I also did a small search to find some kind of button to flag the
>   question as appropriate, but it seemed not to be there.

Once you have [sufficient rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) you will see a `reopen` link under closed questions, where you can vote to reopen. Until then, if you believe a question has been wrongly put on hold, you can either bring it up on Meta or flag for a moderator's attention (in both cases, provide as much detail as you can). Again, in this case, **the question was dealt with appropriately**.

Comment: Mods are generally going to decline most all flags requesting a question be reopened as something that the community should be handling on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Even after the user edited his question, it's still not an appropriate question for the site, and it was correctly left closed.