# Notification on reopening downvoted question

Tags: feature-request, edits, downvotes, notifications

Very often I downvote bad question that later on gets closed. Since, it is site policy that bad question should be edited and improved rather than deleted, it would be nice to receive notification when such downvoted question is edited and reopened as result of such edit.

I would like a chance to review question again and remove my downvote if appropriate. Doing that manually is tedious and there are far too many questions to track them all.

This is similar to [Notification on edit of downvoted content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/notification-on-edit-of-downvoted-content) with one significant difference. Notification would not be sent for every edit, just when and if question is reopened.

Comment: This is something that I would appreciate. I don't downvote often, mainly because it's too complicated to find a question you downvoted and to see if it has been updated in the mean time.

Comment: It so happen that, everyone who `downvoted` they don't cast the vote to close it. I think, it would be better to send notification to `close voters` also on that question.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Close voting does not inflict permanent damage to the question because question can be reopened after editing. But if someone down voted question while it was bad, he/she has no clue that question was edited and reopened. Basically question will still have that down vote which it may no longer deserve.

Comment: Another way of doing "damage control" would be automatic clearance of down votes accumulated before question vas closed, but I would prefer notification so I can decide myself.

Comment: Yes, to remove or take back all the downvotes, it make sense. But people you have voted to close the post, can also contribute to the updated post. So I think it is fair to notify the `close voters` as well

Comment: @YoungHobbit I would see that as additional feature-request separate from this one.

Comment: There's a similar feature-request for general downvoted content: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/notification-on-edit-of-downvoted-content , but that doesn't seem to contain reopening (since it also applies to answers). And again something different yet similar [on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165962/allow-me-to-get-notifications-on-specific-down-voted-questions)

Comment: @KФ http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote

Comment: @mods should this migrate to Meta.SE

Comment: @Braiam yeah like I said I don't downvote often.

Comment: +1, I also think the possibility of people coming pack should be communicated in a close message, to encourage the original poster to edit the bad question and not give up, rage quit or something like that.

Comment: This could potentially spam your inbox.

Comment: @TreviAwater That shouldn't be a problem, re-opened questions are [somewhat rare](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266844/1169519).

Comment: I guess most people wouldn't care for the additional noise. A compromise might be to have small icons signifying changes post-vote on the vote-tab (`?tab=votes`). So interested users get an overview and the rest is not bothered at all. This can then easily be extended to all kinds of votes.

Comment: @Braiam It is hard to find those questions that might have been closed, edited and reopened there.

Comment: @YoungHobbit: If downvotes should be voided on re-open, so should be upvotes. Which probably would lead to an outcry from the same people who want the downvotes removed. And they would have to be re-instated on re-closing or deletion.

Comment: Removing downvotes after a question is reopned would lead to an easy way for groups of people with the close/reopen privilege to rid questions of downvotes

Comment: @Deduplicator I did not mean voiding the downvotes automatically, just because the question is re-opened. I was just agreeing with the OP that down-voters can decide that. It was OPs suggestion for auto clearance of downvotes. I just wanted to say that, users who have voted to close the post should also be notified as they can also contribute to the updated post.

Comment: @YoungHobbit I mentioned possibility of removing downvotes automatically, but that was not my original intention and I don't really like that idea. I was more contemplating about other possible ways of doing damage control including automatic ones. But after revisiting that thought, automatic clearance is not really a good option.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is a good idea, but needs a little bit of tweaking.

Consider following suggested implementation:

- The system is entirely opt-in
- You can choose to get notifications when questions you downvoted are reopened, or choose to get notifications when questions you close-voted are reopened, or both, or neither

Im sure many people would opt into and enjoy this new system, and it would benefit the community members improving their questions alot. As it stands, I rarely undo downvotes I give, because keeping track of what happens to questions you downvoted is both menial and not worth doing by hand.

Comment: So, one should really hope the question gets closed before it gets fixed, then?

Comment: @Deduplicator I would be in favor of even enabling that to notify you if posts you downvoted got edited, but thats not within the scope of this proposal.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, it seems a bit unfair to those that may fix the question before it gets closed. On the other hand, if the question gets fixed soon enough it probably didn't get too many downvotes as it is. I would be in favor of getting notifications for all down voted questions after they have been edited, but that might be too noisy option.