# What to do with my unanswered question? (went through "on hold")

Tags: support, specific-question, unanswered-questions

## Disclaimer:

**I sincerely ask that the reader does not answer the linked question, I don't want this to be perceived as a *bump* on Stack Overflow Meta. And it wouldn't help to narrow the actual effectiveness of the suggested answers to the following:**

---

I asked [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016854/javafx-listview-trims-my-invisible-nodes-that-i-use-for-layout-how-should-i-ap), it was put on hold for very valid reason. I edited, added a sample of code to reproduce ... It got better and was opened again. Got one upvote (from -3 to -2) from one of the reviewer and a couple more views since.

Where I found some help:

- Help center, I followed [those steps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers);
- A blog post: [How to get answers](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/);
- A question that makes mine looking a bit like a duplicate: [Getting attention for unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions). But the situation here is a little different as my question doesn't have **any** answer.

I did what I could to improve the quality of the answer,  making the screenshots visible when I got the rep to do so, rewording the title, double-checking the tags, ... Got some more view (~50 as I write this) but still no answer.

---

After going through the resources linked above, I still have options:

- Answer it myself, I'd do it if I could but still can't;
- Keep editing with new inputs, I'm running short though;
- Use the *mail a friend who might know the answer* feature, WTB such friend;
- Put a bounty, when I have the rep to do so;
- Go to bed still as dumb as I was yesterday.

Is that it? Or Is there any other course of action I'm overlooking? Is delete an option since not a single answer yet?

Alternatively, is the question just (or still) bad? If so, where to get feedback if not here and now?

Comment: Question looks good to me now, I only made the title a little more generic. Unfortunately it can be difficult for a question to turn around after it has already been put on hold and downvoted, it's your question fighting for attention among a huge pile of other questions asked daily. For a higher chance of success I'd go for creating an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Gimby: There’s something wrong with this system. It turns valid questions with a bad start into... taboos: no one is allowed to ask them again (“duplicate question”), yet they have no answers, are locked, and are buried by bad rating. I have the same problem with [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135306/how-do-i-create-a-new-win32-gui-c-project-in-codeblocks). Added perk is that **I have worked out my own answer...** and I’m not even allowed to post it.

Comment: request someone to put bounty on your question

Comment: @Lulero I will copy the latest version of the question, delete it, then ask another question using that latest version of the question. I haven't yet checked if that is bad (_although, I think that is bad_) but that is the only thing I can think of specially after your original question being downvoted so many times now.

Comment: I think it's great that you went through all these efforts to get your question to this exemplary state, so I put a bounty on it to draw some more attention. It's only a 50 point bounty because I'm cheap :)

Comment: @7vujy0f0hy IIRC you can't vote to close as a duplicate of a question that doesn't have an (upvoted / accepted?) answer. So it's only frowned upon if OP asks it again.

Comment: A lot of people have "mission" on SO.  Usually it is to close vote questions.  Now that you have enough rep, your mission could be to scour [an advanced search for: `score:..0 intags:mine closed:false hasaccepted:false hascode:true duplicate:false migrated:false`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=score%3a..0%20intags%3amine%20closed%3afalse%20hasaccepted%3afalse%20hascode%3atrue%20duplicate%3afalse%20migrated%3afalse) sorted by "active" for questions in a similar situation as yours, i.e. editted to decent, but lost in the abyss and upvote them.

Comment: Loosely related [feature-request to notify voters after a question has been reopened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314397/notification-on-reopening-downvoted-question). This would be a huge improvement in my opinion, since downvotes usually indicate to other users something along the lines of "don't click on this question - you'll probably waste your time" which makes it too hard for truly improved questions to gain upvotes (because nobody bothers to click on them any more).

Comment: @7vujy0f0hy: To be fair, your question is still unclear, you may improve it by saying what you wanted to create and what blocked you (even easier if you have your answer ready), remove the bit about the research effort (it show in the question formulation, not by listing the tentatives). Then go in chat and ask for help unlocking it and adding your question

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Thank you, much appreciated and obviously effective. Although it did turn this meta question into sort of a bounty request, which I don't think should be the way (at least not through meta) to address the problem described here. Should have included this too in the disclaimer but I didn't see it coming. Now it's a bit awkward for both the related questions. People won't answer the original because of my disclaimer and the present one lost its illustration. As such, I'd consider the disclaimer void from now but would make more sense with an accepted answer here.

Comment: *People won't answer the original because of my disclaimer* - I don't think so. Just give it some time, apparently the meta effect is well under way (+27 as of now), and people don't read anyway, so if it's answerable, it will be answered... eventually. Bounty hunters will see to it ;-) ...big huge kudos for all the effort you've put in.

Comment: @Lulero It seems that it's indeed very hard to draw attention to questions that went through a bad spell. Not a single answer almost 20 hours after offering the bounty, so I decided to write one myself. The bounty is still open as it can't be awarded to myself, so we'll see if more answers come in in the following days. If not, the answer to your meta question seems to be that there's not a whole lot you can do...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I learnt that I can't accept multiple answers. Accepted yours because the other [doesn't fit as well for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016854/listview-with-custom-cellfactory-trims-invisible-nodes/43231783#comment73546181_43231783) after reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers). As for the answer to the present meta question, I learnt a lot in the process already and I have to agree. Not much more to do. Posting on meta for attention wasn't my intend, nor can be recommended.

Comment: I was going to place a bounty on your question, but someone else already did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The following answer is inferred from the comments generated by the question.*

---

### The issue isn't the question

As stated by various users in the comments without, to date, anyone to say otherwise: **[the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016854/listview-with-custom-cellfactory-trims-invisible-nodes) that triggered this meta one is now in a decent state**.

The steps taken by its author to get there were in line with various helping resources found on Stack Overflow itself ([a page in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers), [a blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/), [a closely related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions)).

---

### "Not a whole lot you can do"

[Original comment by Robby Cornelissen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346419/what-to-do-with-my-unanswered-question-went-through-on-hold?cb=1#comment462360_346419)

Given you:

- **Addressed the issue** pointed out by the users who decided to put your question "on hold"
- Tried your best to **improve the quality of your question** ([need help?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers))

You might still end with a good question with little views and down-votes.

> Unfortunately **it can be difficult for a question to turn around after it has already been put on hold and downvoted**, it's your question fighting for attention among a huge pile of other questions asked daily.

[Original comment by Gimby](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346419/what-to-do-with-my-unanswered-question-went-through-on-hold?cb=1#comment462012_346419)

To **put a bounty on your question** is probably the best way. If you lack the reputation to do so you can still request someone to do so ([suggested by sidgate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346419/what-to-do-with-my-unanswered-question-went-through-on-hold?cb=1#comment462045_346419)).

For the present case, the one put on the original question by Robby Cornelissen ([see the related comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346419/what-to-do-with-my-unanswered-question-went-through-on-hold?cb=1#comment462049_346419)) greatly helped.

---

### How can you help?

No system is perfect, and there's probably something that could be tweaked to avoid similar situations.

- Take the matter into your own hands.

> Your mission could be to scour an advanced search for [questions] edited to decent, but lost in the abyss and upvote them.

[Original comment by Zach Mierzejewski](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346419/what-to-do-with-my-unanswered-question-went-through-on-hold?cb=1#comment462052_346419)

- Think of a new feature for Stack Overflow to deal with those situations and request it. See [Keiwan's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346419/what-to-do-with-my-unanswered-question-went-through-on-hold?cb=1#comment462053_346419) for an example (and avoid at least one duplicate).

Comment: `not a lot you can do`, except to learn from your mistakes.  Bad questions get punished, so make sure your next question is good before asking it rather than fixing it later.  Yeah, that doesn't help _this_ question, but hopefully now your next questions will be better as well. (No, that's not perfect).

Comment: @dave You commented while I was still editing few hours after.  Yes I'm learning a lot, asking something on Stack Overflow has turned into quite the journey. Technically though, this meta question was my 2nd one and was kind of risky (it still could turn out to be a duplicate for all I can tell) but hope it shows I learnt something.

Comment: I’m sorry, @dave. I’m afraid I can’t do that.