# Triaging new users' questions

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I like to spend some time clearing the triage queue for a mental break. Often I meet questions, especially from new users, where they ask something, without code, or all the details required for an answer. My question is:

When we have written something like "Welcome to SO, you need to provide some more information in order for us to provide an answer. Read the how to and try again."

I don't see any of the buttons as fitting.

> **Looks OK** for questions that can be found, understood and answered as-is

This doesn't fit, since the question is not immediately answerable.

> **Requires Editing** for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing.

It does require editing, but not by a SO moderator (I have been told off for using this button wrongly).

> **Unsalvageable** for questions that cannot or should not be answered and must therefore be removed from the site.

There is the "RTFM" how to ask flag, but I wouldn't be happy as a new user getting this flag...

> **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next question.

I am sure what I want, and I have commented on the question.

Should I just use skip anyway?

PS

I have read the guide:

*[Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674)*

and several other discussions regarding this.

I see that this is almost a duplicate of *[Can we please have the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back)* so I will close it.

Comment: You are being called upon to balance the need of the one against the needs of the many.  Favoring the one is a pretty normal human trait, but if you are incapable of *ever* considering the many then you should not review.

Answer (score 16):

**Unsalvageable** is the right option.  Flag to close the question as "unclear what you are asking" (or "off-topic" -> "question must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it").

Quoting the guide you linked to:

> Common reasons for marking a question Unsalvageable include:
>
> [...]
>
> - It concerns an error in source code, but is missing that code… or the error… or both.

You might ask, [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing)  The answers to that question say "You should wait for zero seconds" and "Cast your close vote immediately".  The idea is that the question cannot be answered in its current state, so we'd put it "on hold" while waiting for OP to edit the question.

"Unsalvageable" is perhaps a confusing name for this option.  The question may very well be salvageable by the OP.  This option leads to the question being put "on hold", which either leads to reopening the question after edits, or to the question being closed.

Comment: It is the "unsalveagable" part that "confuses" me

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate choice. If it truly was unsalvageable, @JoSSte wouldn't bother asking for an edit (since it's not salvageable).

Comment: @Clockwork:  "Unsalvageable" is from the perspective of someone that is not the OP.  If I as a reasonable editor cannot save this, it is therefore unsalvageable and only the OP can actually salvage what's left of this question.

Comment: @Makoto exactly, I had to figure out that needs editing, didn't mean that the OP should edit it, but that a moderator with the right knowledgset should edit it. So bottom line, I got wiser, even though i got a negatively rated question. apparently I canøt write high quality Q's myself :-)

Comment: @JoSSte:  Diamond moderators do not edit questions just because they have domain knowledge. There's like thirty of them and they don't cover all areas of expertise, whereas we are legion and can cover many, many more areas of expertise. Don't lull yourself into thinking that only moderators can edit things.

Comment: @Makoto I sometimes meet a question which i may not be able to answer, but see may be easier to understand with a little editing, which i tackle myself. as I wrote in my Q, I mistakenly thought that "requires edit" meant that the OP should edit it... i am not trying to advocate that the moderators should have extra work. as i see it, the whole point of triage is to align and make the moderators' work easier.

Comment: @JoSSteJo OP needs to edit => unsalvageable. Community can edit => requires editing.

Comment: Are there any statistics on how often a question put on hold is actually updated and reopened?

Comment: @Taplar [there was a stat written by Shog in 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266844/2821954)

Answer (score 10):

Review the content, not the user. If a question fits a close reason, the button to click is Unsalvageable - whether it was asked by a new user or Jon Skeet.

Comment: I think that my issue is that the "unsalvageable" needed perspective. I got that now.

Answer (score 1):

And just for the record: the buttons should have different labeling:

- "edit" should say "can be fixed by other community members"
- "unsalvageable" should say "can only be fixed by the questioner"

Or something close to that. After doing hundreds of "help and improvement" edits and talking to dozens of triage reviewers, I am deeply convinced that the simple stupid label "edit" is one of the major reasons why "triage" is broken and most often results in wrong votes.

New reviewers don't understand that difference. That is the real issue here.

Comment: I think that is the essence of what i found out, asking this question