# "Reopen Votes" Review Queue: What's the percentage (statistics) of actually reopened questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, statistics, vote-to-reopen

I basically always select "Leave Closed". So I'm asking: How many questions are actually reopened in total?

In case I'm right in my assumption that this value is very low, I would ask the next question: Are these few questions worth the hassle? Or is the entire "Reopen Votes" Review Queue just a waste of time?

EDIT after comment by @Braiam: I'm talking about these: "This question was edited after it was closed. Should it be reopened?" From my observation, those are the majority in the review queue. And I hardly (almost never) see one being *really* improved...

Comment: Per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550/2019-a-year-in-moderation, over 10,000 questions were reopened in 2019

Comment: Some old stats are available [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266709/how-often-are-closed-questions-re-opened). The details have almost certainly changed since then, but the answer to your question is "more than you think". A staff member will be required to get the updated numbers. Let's let upvotes judge how many other people are eager to see this, and thus whether it's worthy of a staff member's time to try and compile some stats.

Comment: other related questions that came to my mind: How many reopen votes were casted from review? How many reopened questions came into the queue through a vote, and how many through an edit? Given that closure UX is something that the community team is currently working on, this is definetly interesting.

Comment: Interesting question. Could be maybe grouped by close reason to see which close reasons motivate the op to improve and which don't.

Comment: "Are these few questions worth the hassle?" Yes, if only to know how good or bad the whole re-opening process works. The re-opening is also not a big hassle, compared to the other review queues.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402422/we-need-to-improve-the-chances-of-reopening-closed-questions/402486#402486

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Robert Longson's comment, here are the numbers for 2019 (if I'm interpreting the table at [2019: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392550/1668200) correctly):

> Tasks reviewed: Reopen Vote queue: 185,719
>
> Questions reopened: 9,112

So 4.9% of questions in the "Reopen Votes" queue are actually reopened.

Which means that for 95% of all cases, the current "reopening system" doesn't really work out - or more precise: The effort put into improving and reviewing those 95% is futile, since the questions stay closed.

So my original "waste of time" assumption is true for 95% - which certainly means that there's room for improvement ;-)

Comment: Lack of guidance what an edit should look like is probably a major root cause for that.

Comment: '2019 stats are not quite valid for this year because of reopen votes threshold change from 5 to 3. When they tried [experimenting with this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390083/839601) results were that there was noticeable impact on reopening

Comment: So, at what percentage would there be no more "room for improvement"? Because it can't be 100%, since that would mean the people voting to close are completely incompetent and I refuse to believe that, and that there are no people contesting closures despite the validity of the closures, which a quick inspection of Meta SO's question history would shatter...

Comment: @HereticMonkey if 100% of the questions in this queue start out being close-worthy and are then edited so they are no longer close-worthy then the people originally voting to close could were still correct/competent.

Comment: @Marijn Sure and all of the questions in the Reopen Queue could also be invalidly marked as duplicates of a single, highly downvoted question. Or any number of other unlikely scenarios. I'm trying to get a feeling for when we're going to be able to say "good enough". Right now it seems like "perfection or we keep screaming at each other" and that's just not going to end in a lot of rough voices.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was just replying to your comment _it can't be 100% because then all the close voters were wrong_ which is not the case if the reopen process actually does what it is supposed to do, i.e., transform close-worthy questions into acceptable questions. As for the right percentage (because 100% is indeed a bit unrealistic), I don't know, but something more than 5% would be nice.

Comment: Note, that you are munging together all the reasons why reopen tasks are created: by edit, vote or popularity. I remember there was a break down somewhere.

Comment: I would blame how the reopen system works, for these statistics, in that a question can only automatically be voted to be reopened after its first edit.  **Which happens even if the first edit is a rant about the question being closed.**. The community at that point has no choice but to keep it closed.  That’s when the system breaks down.

Comment: The majority of questions I see in the reopen queue were pushed there by cosmetic edits that don't actually change the substance of the question at all. I wonder what the stats are for questions getting reopened after having *meaningful* edits done to them, but of course it'd be hard to filter for that.