# Question of closing

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Its perfectly reasonable to close a question about tool recommendation like the one below - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276812/any-tools-available-to-help-migrate-legacy-windows-6-1-mobile-app-to-windows-8-1.

These are valid questions but in a wrong place i.e.StackOverflow. StackExchange is a big network which should be able to accommodate such questions. A new user posting a valid question as these might find his question getting closed an intimidating experience. On the contrary answers to these questions can be useful to others. After all StackExchange is a repository of helpful but quality data. Being strict on the kind of questions we ask on SO maintains, but are we doing it right? Rules are meant to be changed with time. Is there a site in StackExchange where such recommendation/opinionated/tool related questions can be addressed.

There is a recommendation in the comment to move it to programmers.stackexchange.com. Will it be better if we have a flag for migration as well? So that rather than closing a question right away, it might be useful for OP as well as StackExchange community?

If flagging is not an option, is there any other way to gather knowledge from these kind of questions? Because its in our SO culture to close them and we fail to gather these knowledge. How should we deal this problem in a better way?

Comment: [programmers.se] also doesn't accept "recommendation" questions. We used to have an option to migrate questions there but was removed due to most of the questions being closed there as well.

Comment: Thanks, thats what my feeling as well... We end up closing such questions. That is still a problem isn't it? How do we gather these knowledge in Stack exchange if we end up closing such questions?

Comment: related: [What exactly is a recommendation question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/839601)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, inquiries for recommendations of specific tools/software isn't within the purview of Stack Overflow. There is a different Stack Exchange Community for such requests.

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Closing the question because it doesn't fit the Stack Overflow policy is necessary to keep this Q and A site on its intended path, and to avoid the intimidating nature of a question rejection, the comments must point the asker in the right direction.