# Can I ask question about terms of cloud services or generally services that are strictly for developers on Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I am going to deploy ASP. NET MVC 5.1 application. I don't know if there are cheaper solutions than Azure which will work with ASP .NET MVC 5.1 or there are some catches in terms of Microsoft Azure.

I don't know where to ask this question. If I ask it on SuperUser I will probably not get answers from developers but from consumers at same time If I post it on StackOverflow developers who have first hand expierience with it will read it but the question is not about an exception, a bug etc. so it is going to be downvoted and closed.

Where I should ask this question?

Comment: related: **[Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)**

Comment: Also related: MS directs users to SO for "Azure" help: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/forums/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ask this at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). That is the only site that has a looser policy on recommending off-site resources. You question is off-topic now for both StackOverflow, SuperUser and Serverfault.

Make sure to read their [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) though so you are absolutely sure your question is on-topic there.

Answer (score 8):

You can—in general—ask questions about cloud services directly related to programming. Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on topic here.

However, you cannot ask *these specific* questions.

Whether "cheaper solutions than Azure" exist is a classic, open-ended [recommendation question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question). These are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Whether there are "catches in terms of Microsoft Azure" is not a specific programming question, but rather a "big list"-style question, which are also off-topic.

You can find more information in the Help Center; specifically:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Do note that Super User and Server Fault have very similar rules regarding these types of questions. Please be sure to consult their respective Help Centers before posting a question there, too.