# Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask questions like these on Stack Overflow:

- How long did it usually take to get response from GitHub support?
- How much will I pay right now, if I change GitHub paid plan in the middle of current one?

These questions has nothing to do with recomendations (what is cheaper, what has better support).

Note, that this question isn't related (or duplicate) of [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270278/1469208). I've read it. It's on something else. Guy is asking about terms of services in question and then *magically* goes to recommendations, what is better or cheaper in a particular case.

Comment: Not a programming question -> no.

Comment: The related link in the question you linked should have answered your question ["**Why we're not customer support for your favorite company**"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: @l4mpi - `software tools commonly used by programmers` -> yes.

Comment: @Oded But _pricing_, seriously? That's far off-topic IMO; and I don't see any worth in storing that information on SO. Unlike hard programming facts, the vendor is free to change this at a whim.

Comment: @l4mpi - agreed. Pricing is off-topic, in particular as it will change over time. Tool questions are OK (as far as specific usage by programmers), but pricing does fall outside of that. Just put that out there as a counter point to your first comment, which some people take way too much to heart, and incorrectly at that.

Comment: This is a good question, so have my upvote. But keep in mind that these kinds of question you mention are off-topic, ok?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First things first, those questions are not about problems that you would solve with code. Some people may think that since they deal with tools used by programmers that would be ok, but those kinds of questions are not related to programming. You could ask the same questions about your phone company, or some cable TV subscription.

I think those questions would be off topic even on any other IT related, but less programming oriented site on the Stack Exchange (such as Server Fault or Super User), for the following reasons:

- If you want to know about prices, you can always contact the vendor. I assure you a vendor will always have more up-to-date, accurate knowledge about their prices than any SE expert at any time.
- As for how long tech support from your favorite services takes to respond, any answer would be too localized in time to be useful to anyone. For example, if Github's staff took an average two days to respond to issues on February this year, who could guarantee that they would keep the same timeframe nowadays, or next year?

Comment: The thing is that Google redirects to Stack Overflow when you try to ask them a question.