# Library recommendations are off-topic, but this one was so useful - what can be done to meet this demand?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, recommendation-questions

Today I was looking for an answer to a question that I knew would not be welcomed on SO. Surprisingly, Google showed such question was asked on SO but unsurprisingly the question was deleted. To my absolute relieve, Google cached the page and I was able to get some extremely useful information from it.

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ZYWkkRQpXqMJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/20424477/responsive-sortable-list-supporting-drag-drop-for-bootstrap+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

(Direct link: [How can I implement a touch-sensitive, responsive, sortable list supporting drag & drop for Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20424477))

This happened to me more than once.

I understand the "not-constructive" policy exists for a reason but you guys are missing on something. Sometimes the fastest way to solve a problem is to ask your peers, ask for opinion or experience. There is a demand for such kind of questions and where is demand there will be a startup to address it. It would be to a great benefit for everyone if you could find a way to accommodate this type of questions while not lowering the standards of this amazing portal.

Comment: Well, make a proposal for how to do that. Otherwise, this is just **not constructive**.

Comment: you are so funny, you totally got me.

Comment: There are oodles of *forums* (which SO is not)  around for that sort of thing.  an "SA" chat room might also get you what you want.

Comment: On meta, downvotes only mean amicable disagreement. Nothing personal

Comment: @Deduplicator - SA is StackOverflow , apparently .

Comment: @Coffee Downvotes *can* mean a lot of things.  *One* of them is amicable disagreement.  It's far from the *only* thing they mean.

Comment: SA is [cooking.se], @Coffee. And he's right, that question would *not* be welcomed there.

Comment: @Shog9  - Ah yes, seasoned advice :-D

Answer (score 18):

That question was deleted because, instead of focusing on a specific problem, the author formulated a broad request for library recommendations. These have repeatedly demonstrated themselves to be problematic, and this question was no exception:

- One answer recommended the very library the asker was already trying (without success) to use, including no advice on actually solving the asker's problems.
- Three answers consisted of recommendations with no example code or other indication that they would actually solve the asker's problems.
- One answer described how to use the library the asker was trying to use successfully, only to run into an additional requirement that hadn't been explicitly noted in the question.
- The last answer (posted **a full year after the question was asked!**) recommended a different library that would satisfy all requirements, and included example code.

So, 4 out of 6 answers were completely worthless, and history has shown these questions to be magnets for such cruft. Thus the reason for closing and deleting.

That said, there *is* another option: **editing!** If such a question has managed to attract good answers in spite of itself, it is possible for anyone to go in and re-write it to **reflect the underlying problem**, dropping the broad resource-request and discouraging or invalidating lousy answers in the process.

So I did this. [The question is now undeleted, with only two answers remaining...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424477/how-can-i-implement-a-touch-sensitive-responsive-sortable-list-supporting-drag)

Note that the close reason used recommends *exactly this:*

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. **Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.**

(emphasis mine)

So, next time you run across a question requesting library recommendations where someone has taken the time to look past the superficial question and address the *actual problem faced by the author*, **use this technique to salvage it.**

Comment: I agree that this was all good, and I salute your resuscitation of the page, but note that this process is not likely to be one that the author of this Meta question -- with ~1K rep -- could successfully perform, since it would involve getting the edit reviewed (to cries of "changing meaning!" "invalidating answers!") and the answers deleted via a flag about their technical merits, which moderators don't like handling.

Comment: Moderators are usually pretty ok with deleting link-heavy, downvoted answers... Unless the question is crap too, in which case there's a more expedient solution. So the trick is, make the question look good, and the answers look like crap. Obviously, this is a lot easier if you start *before* the question gets deleted...

Answer (score 10):

One of the primary reasons the site has been as successful as it is, and why it's managed to create as much high quality content as it has, is specifically because it *doesn't* allow questions that don't meet its standards.

Removing the standards for questions can't be done while maintaining the standard of quality of answers.

Comment: I thought you will appreciate feedback. How naive of me.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek You realize that your question is like going to your doctor and asking how you can lose a bunch of weight while still not exercising and eating tons of unhealthy food.  As much as you'd like a magic pill that will give you everything you want, all you're actually going to hear is *you can't*.  He's not "ignoring your feedback" when you say he's doing a bad job of doctoring by not giving you your magic pill.  He's just informing you of the reality of the situation.

Comment: @Denial, I would argue about your sense of entitlement, but a moderator would probably delete my comment anyway. Just keep in mind this site is a *community*, a community has *rules*, and people expect you to *follow* these rules, even if you think breaking them would be constructive feedback.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I have voiced my opinion in a meta forum that is designed for that purpose. The post is tagged DISCUSSION. How is that breaking your rules??? OMG what's wrong with you people?

Comment: @Daniel, well, we're not a forum, but let that slide for now. Surely you must realize that you're not the only one that comes here, argues about the rules, and tells us we're "missing on something". After a while and a few dozen users, this tends to get a little boring. Have you searched around for other posts with the same idea as yours before asking?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't want this to sound like ad hominem but *[removed. If you don't want to, then don't do it. --The Staff.]*? I gave you feedback. In a good faith. Where do I argue about the rules? How am I breaking them? By giving feedback?

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek-  Ok, time to step aside and take a walk. Really , it is good for Meta newcomers to lurk for a *while* before posting feature-requests/complaints. Meta is very.. *rough* , from an intellectual stand

Comment: Don't worry, never again after this experience. If this is your attitude towards good intended, nicely worded feedback then you don't deserve it.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek - there is a misundersanding.. again, please learn the protocol/culture  on Meta .  hope you continue to help