# Is it considerable to close a protected question?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, vote-to-close, protected-questions

I'm talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838724/is-there-a-barcode-recognition-framework-for-ios), which pops up in [Reviews queue of Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6832791).

Qualities  of this question are:

- Up voted with **155** votes (and no down votes) which favorited by 116 users.
- Oldest question - asked 5 years back.
- Having 30 answers and the accepted answers have **74** votes.
- Protected question.
- Viewed by 92k+ users.

Other notes,

- The accepted answer is outdated.
- But have an updated answer too which considerable work for new iOS versions.

This question flag for off-topic and should be close?

---

However, in my daily routine, when I was reviewing if I find a question in which OP is asking for frameworks or sample code or a software or a tool, then I simply close it with a off-topic vote.

**What should I've to do with this question case?**

Answer (score 4):

While you *can* and *should* certainly also moderate old questions, consider just editing them to correct their deficits and preserve their usefulness.

I just did, and now the qustion should conform to the new site standards.

---

A more elaborate answer by Shog9, where he [remodelled and reinstated a deleted recommendation-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284018).

Comment: Kinda broad now, isn't it?

Comment: It's a how-to-question. And without knowing the answer(s), it might seem be a bit broad. Though not quite too much, especially considering the questions antiquity...

Comment: I'm in a doubt, because I'd already faced such reviews in which, I supposed to close it because OPs didn't show any work on the problem they're facing, they simply ask, "*How to do this in this language?*" and I've seen many reviewers who simply mark it as close with either **too-broad** or **primary opinion based** or **off-topic** with "*why this code is not working*" flag. Lets take the same case with this question (with respect to your edits)?

Comment: @Hemang: Added a reference to a good post by Shog9.

Answer (score 3):

If a question is off-topic with today's rules, close it as such, regardless of how many upvotes it has. This question asks for third-party tools or software, which is off-topic. Closing the question now will prevent that the question will collect opiniated and spammy answers.

When voting on such questions, which I would discourage, keep in mind that these questions were on-topic back when they were asked. Downvoting just because the question has since then become off-topic seems unfair to me.

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with you. When this question asked it was on-topic, but now its considered as off-topic. However in my experience till date, the topic covered in that question is on-topic. Checkout the last answered date, which said that, from iOS7 and above those suggested SDKs (in accepted answer) will not longer worked and have to use iOS provided way to achieve this. However I'm still considering to **leave it open** as its in queue of questions which should not closed as they always come up (in top results) when you look for it in search engines.

Comment: And of course, there'll most probably chance that someone will answer to this question when they found some other possible ways. This will surely keep that question up-to-date.

Comment: The problem isn't that people don't keep it up-to-date, but that questions in that format will attract people that want to plug their product, library or solution. Questions in that format just beg for spam, which is why they are now off-topic. If moderators didn't want us to touch the question and it's answers they would lock it instead, not just protect.

Comment: Correct ! Lets see, who'll come out and take some noticeable action.

Answer (score 1):

It was only protected to prevent more answers from getting added, it has 14 deleted ones right now.  More significantly, the question has a *hundred thousand* views.  Funny things happen when that many people view a question.  Keep in mind that if 100,000 people looked at it then having 155 of them finding the question useful is not all that impressive anymore.  So don't be overwhelmed by the number of votes.

A question can only ever acquire that many views when it is favored by Google and displayed as a top result for a query like "How can I scan barcodes on iOS?"  That probably happened, Google used to like SO a lot.  But it does not anymore.  In fact, the question doesn't show up at all when I look at the first 5 pages of result.  SO posts are not ranked high either, the top result is one for Infragistics.  Oh dear.  There are a few SO hits further down the list.  But they are much more specific questions, the kind we favor today.

So, realistically, there is no conceivable point in still having this question around.  The only thing it really does is giving a Google a reason to not like us anymore.  Because we are keeping this litter around, probably link-trapping visitors to other barcoding questions.  Voting to close is pretty pointless, not enough SO users are going to find it so it can't acquire enough votes to progress to next stage.  Then needing another 20-odd SO users to delete it.

Inevitable conclusion: it should be deleted, only a moderator can do it.

Comment: Have you cast a custom flag yet? Has it been handled? How?

Comment: @JanDvorak for a question with "hundred thousand views", meta discussion is likely more appropriate way than flagging