# If this question is not on-topic on Stack Overflow, where would it be?

Tags: support, specific-question, scope, closed-questions, site-recommendation

I have recently asked [Where is the missing page in the Gameboy Programming Manual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211050/where-is-the-missing-page-in-the-gameboy-programming-manual).

It has, as of now, accumulated 17 views, one downvote and 5 close votes, and has been put on hold. Nobody bothered to give a constructive comment on how to improve it.

Admittedly, the question is very localized, and does, in a way, ask for an offsite resource. However, I do think that clear-cut questions regarding issues with specifications and documentation can be immensely helpful to other people with similar problems.

Also, I don't see anything opinion based in the question, but maybe my wording was unclear? What I really wanted to ask was, "There is a hole in this documentation - what / where is the information that is missing?"

Would there be a way to make questions like that about hardware specifications and / or API documentation on-topic on Stack Overflow? And how would I go about achieving that with the specific question I linked?

Comment: Oh... meta effect ... come on ....

Comment: I don't think that will be a fit on any Stack Exchange site as it is most likely something that only Nintendo would be able to answer

Comment: @JoeW I was hoping there would be errata to the manual or maybe a printed version that includes the missing page.

Comment: @JoeW also, in that case, "it does not exist" would be a valid answer, but I doubt that is true,

Comment: You shouldn't need any comments from anyone. The close text already mentions: _If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question._ Have you done this?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis not yet. The comment sais to "instead describe the problem" which is, imo, exactly what I have done. the problem is missing documentation.

Comment: Your question is basically asking if there is a typo with a page being incorrect or the appendix being wrong. Since you appear to be getting your copy from a third party source there is no way to verify the accuracy of it. The only way would be to get an official copy from Nintendo or for them to say what is going on.

Comment: @JoeW I am not saying there is a typo, I am saying there is a missing page. I also know the appendix is correct.

Comment: `I was surprised to find this official document littered with various mistakes, the most prominent of which in my opinion is the duplicated page 110, which replaces page 111.` Looks to my like you are saying that page 111 is incorrect as it was replaced by a duplicate of the previous page. You should try and get a copy from Nintendo yourself rather then from a third party site.

Comment: see also: [Library recommendations are off-topic, but this one was so useful - what can be done to meet this demand?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284021/839601)

Answer (score 15):

It is asking for an off-site resource and as such closed correctly.

I'm not sure if this variant would be better but let voting decide:

> In Gameboy programming you can use the following  4 instructions CCF, SCF, DI and EI based on what is said in the index of [this manual](http://www.chrisantonellis.com/files/gameboy/gb-programming-manual.pdf). As the actual page (111) is missing I have to guess their use
>
> - Does `CCF` toggle the CY flag in the CPU?
> - Does `SCF` set the CY flag in the CPU?
> - Does `DI` disable the interrupts?
> - Does `EI` enable the interrupts?
>
> I ran the following in the emulator but I don't think my assumption  about `DI` is correct:
>
> ```
> awesome code here
> ```
>
> What is the correct use of `DI` and `EI`?

This is no longer asking for a resource, it shows effort, it is a practical answerable question for any-one familiar with that type of CPU (which shows remarkable resemblance with a [Zilog Z80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80)/[Intel 8080](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080)).

Comment: hm, thanks for the suggestion - I think I understand now where I went wrong. It's really hard not to get emotional when something you make gets stomped into the ground and spat on without so much as a comment, even if it's just a four-paragraph question... I will try and ask a better question next time :)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin *"hard not to get emotional when something you make gets stomped into the ground and spat on without so much as a comment"* - Your skin must be painfully thin if you call mere community moderation "being stomped and spat on". A bit theatrical, don't you think? not exactly nice to the people who were just doing the right thing.

Comment: @Gimby that might all be true but not everyone is emotional detached from their post directly after posting. Not sure what you want to achieve with your comment except stomping and spitting on a user.

Comment: I am considering deleting this question and the one I linked - I don't think they provide enough merit to stay around, but I am not really sure I know what I am doing..? what do you think @rene?

Comment: I would keep this one but if you delete the SO one take a screenshot and include that and add that you deleted the question. It is eligible for the Roomba anyway in its current state, in the next 9 days.