# How I can improve this question

Tags: discussion, questions, on-hold

I asked this question and it received several down-votes just few seconds after posting, I doubt most of down-voters even read the question body.
I'm mainly looking for list of topics which should I learn, not necessarily specific book titles.

How I can improve [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135500)?

[image]

Comment: As you've deleted the question, I can't be sure, but maybe it's more appropriate for programmers.se?

Comment: maybe, I re-posted it on [programmers.se][1]

  [1]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/271064/programming-language-implementation-and-tools

Comment: yeah, maybe I am in the wrong direction or I can't describe my question well.

Comment: We don't need to read the entire thing.  Within three seconds I can see the bolded "looking for list of topics" at which point I know it's off topic.  List of Things questions have been off topic for years and years.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is off-topic for the site; it has already been closed as such. Please review the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what kind of questions are off-topic.

The on-hold banner on the post tells you clearly why it was closed and what, if anything, could be done to remedy it:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Your post was probably down-voted because people expected you to have done that research (finding out if a question is on-topic) before posting it.

Even after editing your question remained too broad and asked for a list of things to learn; the Stack Exchange Q&A format isn't suitable for such questions.

Comment: I have clarified the question, do it is still off-topic for this site? Thanks.

Comment: @sudoer your question is far too broad, and still asking for opinions and lists.

Comment: How is that question off-topic whilst http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list are protected?

Comment: They are curated by the community. The two posts are not by individuals.

Comment: Yes, but they were started by individuals, then converted.

Comment: They were started years ago when the site rules were different; we have since learned (the hard way) that such questions generally don't work in the Q&A format, unless rigorously curated. Those posts are kept in their current form only as long as they are actively maintained.

Comment: [Why is "the definitive C++ book list" question allowed, but other book recommendation questions are not?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144359) @PhilLello