# Do I use SO to ask for code sample/solutions?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Would I use SO to ask a question about looking for code samples or solutions that can read/write a standardised file format? [e.g. `Australian Payments Clearing Association's Direct Entry file specification`, used by all Australian banks].

Comment: There also [the Software Recommendations sister site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  You couldn't ask for sample code there, but you could ask for a library that performs the task (and its documentation should have usage samples)

Comment: @BenVoigt Please be aware of the strict rules over on SR. I've added your suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, those type of questions fall in [Some questions are still off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) category:

4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Instead you could start on your own, implementing a reader or writer for that format and ask a question when you are stuck. Good chance someone answers, maybe with a link to more material.

As  [Ben stated in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285640/do-i-use-so-to-ask-for-code-sample-solutions/285642?noredirect=1#comment153052_285640) you could ask for a library on SoftRec. But if you do please take note of the following rules.

**tl;dr don't post *I search for a library to do X* on SR because it will fail miserably**

> If you visit [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) you'll find this text on their [on-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:
>
> > Good software recommendation requests have two components:
> >
> > - A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
> > - Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features
>
> Beyond this they have a post with [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) that require you to post the correct content in the correct format.
>
> On content expect to provide at least: the kind of application you're looking for; the operating system to be used; your budget; needs and features of the application
>
> For formatting you have to make sure that your post has a clear title and it's features should be listed in order of importance.
>
> Visit [their meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/) for extra guidance.

<sup>Adapted from [my own answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248181/158100)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I've certainly made a start and am porting our old code to new, but it's a shame there's only a loose collection of blog posts and very little guidance beyond the spec. (I'm sure I could do it much better). I will look at Ben Voigt's suggestion about Software Recommendations too.

Comment: @PeterX please check my additional edit before you go the SR route!