# Why doesn't SE implement poll functionality?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, opinion-based

I think there should be a poll function for questions here.

I don't actually get the argument behind "recommending software is A Terrible Thing, And We Don't Do That".

[Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779260/any-python-module-to-get-the-functionlity-of-unix-find-command) And here is why it's "wrong": [(1)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question), [(2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194674/is-there-a-stackexchange-site-for-asking-about-software-products-that-fulfill-re).

Actually, it is quite normal to ask "what library provides feature Z", then look at the list of answers and then do the usual SE thing -- start from the ones that are top voted.

Oh, wait, it would be *opinion-based*. So what? [SE does not seem to be afraid of duplicates](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), then why is it all of a sudden scared of opinions?

*But the answer will change with time*. Well, same is true about any software-related question. That's the main point of software having releases, you know.

*That is really a poll, not a SE question.* Hm-m. here we have the heaviest collection of programmers who may share their professional opinions. Why don't we let them share it via a poll?

Comment: I admire the speed of down voting. OTOH, the linked questions have about the same number of down votes. Same angry guys everywhere?

Comment: You know down-voting on meta means disagreement and has nothing to do with the quality of your post?

Comment: The answer is simple: It was tried, it didn't work out, we don't do that anymore. And we don't see that anything about human nature (or the SE system) has changed (fundamentally enough).

Comment: @deduplicator: Not sure about that: It perfectly works for the old "frozen" questions. ( Still use the answers from these polls when I find them. ) Thanks a lot for the answer, though.

Comment: @rene: nope, I'm an infrequent user. thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @ジョージ: you cannot see what had to be deleted from all those posts though. The type of question requires a disproportionate amount of moderation work. We simply cannot keep up the Stack Overflow quality you expect on such posts, it doesn't scale.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: Ivariable, someone wants SE to support everything, because this is where the expertise is, not realizing that the expertise is here *because* the narrow focus is maintained.  You'd kill that which makes SE great, all in the name of trying to use the expertise in a manner it hates.

Comment: I'll mention that [slant.co](http://www.slant.co/) was (IIRC) inspired partly because Stack Overflow lacks a polling feature. They designed a site that maintains a narrow focus of *just* polling (just as Stack Overflow is *just* Q&A) and appear to be reasonably successful at that (it wouldn't be a place to ask a Q&A question, just as polling doesn't work here).

Comment: @MichaelT Isn't it strange, though, that as separate these sites seem to work well? ( And thanks a lot for the link -- it may be what I was looking for )

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Isn't it strange, though, that the best programmer's community can not come up with a solution that *does* scale?

Comment: @ジョージ: this site is the best because it picked a focus and *sticks to it*. A good developer knows how to use their strengths. There are other sites that focus on the poll model.

Comment: @ジョージ it is difficult to make a site that accepts all things and is all things for all people... and does them all well. It is much easier to make a site (or engine for a site) that does *one* thing well and focus on that. Stack Exchange does Q&A well. Discourse (Jeff's other project) does discussions well. Slant does polling for the best well. Quora does anecdotes... reasonably. Reddit and Slashdot do discussion on posts ok. Trying to find a solution to a problem in /r/java is an effort in futility compared to searching SO. The key to each is doing what they do well and focusing on that.

Comment: (as an aside, I've often glanced at [What are the best programming fonts?](http://www.slant.co/topics/67/~what-are-the-best-programming-fonts) and found that I really like Source Code Pro - but would find that question likely to be really poorly asked and answered on Stack Overflow or a similar SE site - note though how the format is optimized for polls, easy to add pros and cons (and citations/sources) and comments on existing entries... slant has focused on getting polling right, just as SE has focused on Q&A. How successful each is at their goal is a matter of debate.)

Comment: @MichaelT: Thank you for your comment. I have things to say, but let's keep this site doing just one thing and doing it right )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The poll functionality is implemented naturally, it's just not a wise idea to use it as such.

Software recommendations SE is now existing in beta and if you look at it the answers aren't much more than a poll. Nobody knows if this particular SE will make it.

Moderator elections are polls in Q&A format.

Proposals (as answers) on Meta are polls.

Ask Ubuntu keeps and tolerates an overview about popular Linux distributions which is a poll, and they keep it because it is useful all the same.

But otherwise polls do not work in approximately 99.999% of the cases. People never come back and sometimes even cannot change the vote (anyway they probably wouldn't) to keep the answers updated. And it would be too much work to constantly reavaluate the a given vote. On the other hand I care much more for pros and cons than about what others prefer, so I can choose according to my personal requirements. And if the statistics is too low, i.e. not at least a 100 participants, a poll is even skewed (not to speak of normalizations like age, sex, country, profession).

Finally, you don't need a poll to find out that JQuery is a popular Javascript library, just have a look at the upvoted answers of interesting questions in your field and what they require - and you automatically know what is needed and popular.

So, Coke or Pepsi? Not a question for SO.

Comment: That's a beautiful answer.  (May be except for the last part: my point was that I'd like to know what's *available* -- so both answers count.) Thank you.