# Is it a good idea to ask if there are tools or technology available for a specific task?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, recommendation-questions

I often find myself in situations where I have a project idea that might involve things that I don´t really know anything about and I´m not even aware if there´s technology available to accomplish the task I have in mind.

My question is whether it´s a good idea to ask here if there are tools or technology available to accomplish the specific project I have in mind in a given amount of time.

If not, is there an appropriate place in Stack Exchange to ask this type of questions?

Comment: Doable? Possible? Both seem to be the same question, and both are too broad.

Comment: Also opinion will come into it. And off-topic for recommendation...

Comment: I usually flag those types of questions as off topic. so you can ask all you want, but I wouldn't be surprised if the question gets closed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I´m not even aware if there´s technology available to accomplish the task I have in mind.

Of course there is a technology available - it's called *programming.* What you don't know is whether there's a shortcut or not...

...or whether a shortcut is even needed.

I've seen folks asking about the availability of tools for accomplishing things that are first-class features of their chosen platform - literally the things that are used in advertising and can be accomplished with a bit of trivial code *from the official documentation*. There's no shame in not *knowing* this, but *assuming* it doesn't exist because your research didn't turn up anything is foolish - it turns what could be an honest question into [**an X-Y problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):

> To avoid falling into this trap, always include information about a broader picture along with any attempted solution. If someone asks for more information, or especially a more specific question, do provide details. If there are other solutions which you believe will be suggested and which you've already ruled out, then don't try to avoid going over them again – instead state why you've ruled them out, as this gives more information about your requirements and helps others provide better answers.

If the problem you're facing is "How do I do X?" then **ask exactly that!** Provide details on your situation, on the research you've done, etc... But **don't assume that a solution will take a specific form** - if you *knew* a given task would require a tool or library, **then you'd already know the answer** and you wouldn't be asking the question.

#### See also: [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question/254394#254394)

Answer (score 10):

That kind of question seems too broad for Stack Overflow. I doubt there's anywhere on the SE network where it would be accepted.

> My question is if it´s a good idea to ask here if there are tools or technology available...

That part sounds like a tool or other off-site resource recommendation. Definitely off-topic.

> ...specific project I have in mind can be accomplished at a given amount of time.

That part sounds too subjective. We don't know what your abilities are, so we can't really judge what you can do in a given amount of time.

Comment: The advice I give to everyone who asks that sort of question (I give this advice as I close the question): Try something. See what works, what doesn't. When you have pain, then come ask us about that specific pain.

Answer (score 8):

**No**, thats not a good question at all.

For starters you can, in theory, write a program to do pretty much *anything* (My lack of a theoretical CS degree notwithstanding). So asking if its doable doesn't really ask for much.

Even time isn't a good question, because maybe I program much faster than you (or much slower) so my estimate of how long a given project would *take* isn't useful.

Basically, these questions are entirely opinion-based, and not fit here, or anywhere else on SE.