# Precise definition of off-topic subjects & close-happy problems

Tags: discussion, support, scope, close-reasons

I see more and more closed questions, without any clear explanation - or maybe there are now so many rules that it's becoming impossible to ask a question.

As an example:

> I need to write a demo that involves controlling the T500RS, reading
>   the values of the sensors and setting the force feedback motor.
>
> Unfortunately, I couldn't find any relevant information, could someone
>   point me in the right direction? Is there a library, an SDK?
>
> The platform is Windows 7, C# language but a C++ library/source is
>   fine. Actually, only the specifications would be better than nothing.

Here is the "justification":

*"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

But this question did not ask for a *recommendation*, the OP is only asking to people who have the experience with these devices, *how* it must be done. It's not subject to debate, nor spam, anymore than asking e.g. how to count how many matches a regular expression has in a text.

How should a developer should get an answer regarding this type of problem - it is obviously a general problem here on SE?

Comment: Maybe those 5 close voters are all human and made a mistake?

Comment: Or they saw the text `Is there a library, an SDK?`

Comment: Anyway, the question is still too broad.  `Unfortunately, I couldn't find any relevant information, could someone point me in the right direction?`  Very broad.

Comment: If it gets re-opened I would close it against the same reason... if you have no clue where to start you expect us to write a tutorial, which is too broad. If you have already stuff going but failed to include where you're stuck, it is unclear. In its current form, one-way or the other this question should be closed.

Comment: Hmm, so maybe I should have avoided the words "library" and "SDK"? Or restrict to, let's say, "the part of the .NET API that manages such devices"?

Comment: @rene: not a tutorial, but at least a starting point

Comment: That is what all the newbies say as well....

Comment: @rene: yes, I don't know much about that particular topic, hence the question. Isn't this site supposed to help people who are stuck? As you can see, I was quite happy to spend time helping other newbies.

Comment: _"Isn't this site supposed to help people who are stuck?"_ No, that's just a side effect. This site is here to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers related to programming. Asking for a library or other off-site resource invites spam answers, not to mention that, given the nature of technology, answers can quickly become outdated or obsolete. Answers are also not necessarily voted based on _quality_ but instead on, "Oh, I use this framework!" and the question becomes far less useful. (The top answer could easily be an obsolete, once-popular library, for example.)

Comment: @RedGlyph no, not really. The site exists to have questions that are answerable on a few paragraph based on an actual programming issue. Questions where the OP has no solid ground under their feet would require to much tutoring for the Q and A model the SE sites want to be.

Comment: Related: [Is it a good idea to ask if there are tools or technology available for a specific task?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288002)

Comment: @rene: I understand that, it's not the case. From an info I just received, it should apparently be done with DirectInput. There you are, a simple answer to a simple question, no need for a tutorial, though many questions here still need a lenghty answer (and I don't see a problem in that). But now it's more and more obvious people are just happy to downvote and play god closing questions. This very question is a good example.

Comment: Anyway, thanks to the few who were constructive!

Comment: @RedGlyph I guess I didn't belong to the constructive group? Still, what is next with DirectInput? That is a beast of an API with tons of functions, structs and messages?

Comment: @RedGlyph I usually point askers of such questions to this meta post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question . Asking for "a starting point" (library or not) is nowhere near specific enough to be useful on SO.

Comment: @RedGlyph now that you have DirectInput, what if tomorrow I find a library that ALSO does this, in a different way, and then post this as an answer? and in a month, JoeCoder does his own library doing the same... you can see how this will turn into a flamewar quickly?

Comment: @rene: no, you did, by giving a good point of view.

Comment: @Kendra and Patrice: of course, technology does evolve, API's change, libraries become obsolete, others a created. But if we close all the threads for which the answer may vary in 1 month or 1 year, it would mean closing 95% of them. That is not a good reason to close a question.

Comment: Placing the word "justification" in quotes makes me want to punch a baby.

Comment: @RedGlyph If you re-read my comment, that's not the only reason. Just a part of it. The main reasons are that it invites spam answers and that the voting is more of a popularity poll than based on the quality of the answer. For example, if you write a really well-written answer detailing how to use your favorite library and what functions to call and everything, and I write a one line answer of "Use [insert library here]" and the library I suggested is super popular, there's a decent chance that my answer will be far more upvoted even though yours is far better in terms of quality.

Comment: @RedGlyph I'm sorry but it is. We don't like link only, and a library is mostly a link only. I'm not saying the system as it is is perfect, but Stack Exchange decided to NOT let these questions fly (honestly, I understand why, Stack should not host ALL the questions about coding in the world). We're just giving you the reasoning behind their choice

Comment: Also note that those two main reasons are _in the close reason itself._ As for the fact these libraries change and go obsolete quickly, this just means that the answers get hard to maintain, especially when you don't have a whole lot of restrictions to narrow down your request. In your case, you don't, so there could be dozens of libraries you could use, and more every day. The answers would get hard to maintain, update, and, when needed, prune. Not, by itself, a reason to _close,_ just something to keep in mind about these types of questions.

Comment: @Will: don't worry, there are therapies to overcome this problem ;)

Comment: I doubt there *will* be much information on *hacking the T500RS*, as I doubt many people have done it.  But I'm sure many people **have** hacked similar USB devices.  Go investigate these and learn how it's done.

Comment: Look what I did--I searched for interacting with USB HIDs and found many links, such as http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/ (assuming the t500 reports as a HID under devices).  Go from there, be free, allow me to punch many babies.

Comment: Using search engines is as easy as punching babies https://github.com/thomerow/usb-hid-library

Comment: @Will can I punch some with you?

Comment: @Will OK, I'm going to _drown some kittens_ now, because of this.

Comment: @Will _"BABY PUNCHING PARTY AT MY CRIB"_ You love being _politically incorrect_, don't you? (same for me BTW)

Comment: @Will how do I find your crib? I just follow the babies' cries?

Comment: @Patrice I would tell you, but I'm afraid that would be the tipping point where this comment thread got too long and a mod would come and deleted it.

Comment: Yeah, it's funny, but I've also noted that when I ask a question that violates the site rules/policy, I get down/close voted too.  It's kinda weird, isn't it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How is...

> Unfortunately, I couldn't find any relevant information, could someone point me in the right direction? Is there a library, an SDK?
>
> The platform is Windows 7, C# language but a C++ library/source is fine. Actually, only the specifications would be better than nothing.

... not **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource**?

There is no specific question there at all on-topic for SO.

---

If it was worded as:

> I need to write a demo that involves controlling the T500RS, reading the values of the sensors and setting the force feedback motor.
>
> I've tried using C# with the XYZ library on Windows 7 with the following code:

```
Insert imaginary code block here
```

> However I'm receiving **insert error here** when trying to do so...

How do I fix this?

**That's then a valid question** for SO.

Comment: The specific question is "which library must be used to access that category of device". Can't be more specific than that, if I knew more I wouldn't have to ask... I just don't understand how I should put the question.

Comment: @RedGlyph "which __library__ "  questions are off-topic.

Comment: @RedGlyph Your question in _no way_ reads as "which library must be used" but instead as "Is there a library I can use?" The latter is 100% off-topic, and the former... I would also say is off-topic, as you're still _asking for a library_. If you think you can reword your question to make it on-topic, feel free to do so.

Comment: So it's fundamentally impossible to ask this question? No rewording possible obviously. It's weird.

Comment: @Jon Clements: thanks for the update. However, it's not mandatory to put a piece of code for a question to be valid. I find it awkward to invent any dummy code lest my question be closed ;)

Comment: @RedGlyph SO is for *specific* problems... the site learned a long time back that open ended questions such as this... just lead to opinion, bias and  generally non great answers - that might not even answer your question, then you follow up saying "oh but I meant to say I wanted... or I can't use that because...", then it degrades from there.

Comment: @RedGlyph imagine a question that said "Can anyone recommend me a car" - I could say... well actually... the Bugatti is a lovely car... you then respond - "yeah, but I can't afford that"... so someone else recommends a sports coupe, but you respond saying "yeah, but I need four doors...", so someone else then says, this has 4 doors, but you don't want that one because you want a diesel rather than petrol etc... It goes nowhere, and it tends to go nowhere with a lot of noise very quickly

Comment: @Jon Clements: I see your point, but I'm convinced there can't be so many ways to control such a device. I'm not asking for the "best way" to access it, just "how to access" it. It's apparently through DirectInput. Now, I suspect many will see this as a *recommendation*, because they are not knowledgable, and too eager to give an opinion on a question they don't understand. Maybe as you suggested, by enumerating a few possible way to access the device and why it can't be done would have helped, but in this case it would have been awkward. Anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: @RedGlyph The explanations above aren't necessary. The conversation could have stopped at --  _"which library" questions are off-topic_ -- Your question asked users to find a library, that's all there is to it.

Comment: " I suspect many will see this as a recommendation, because they are not knowledgable, and too eager to give an opinion on a question they don't understand" -- Yes. It is everyone *else's* problem.

Comment: Even if the meaning is the same why we need all this words game?