# How to request question unlocking?

Tags: support, historical-lock

I don't understand why this question is locked as "off-topic": [Is there a Wikipedia API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api)

How does one suggest it be unlocked?

If the answer is by mentioning it here, then consider it mentioned.

Comment: That question is off-topic for the current standards. It's kept around as a reference but won't be re-opened or unlocked.

Comment: I'm one of the more liberal voices in regards to the content that should be on Stack Overflow (I think) but I'm having trouble seeing why that question should exist at all. What value does it add that Googling `Is there a Wikipedia API?`  doesn't provide? This is a prime case where SO questions occupy the most valuable search result slots while the *actual answer to the question* has #3 and should be on the top. (yes, the SO question that occupies #2 has very valuable answers but its  title should be massively rephrased to something like "how do I parse Wikipedia?")

Comment: @Pekka웃, that's weird, you ask the right question but I think your answer is wrong. Read the answers for this question: they're much more diverse and helpful than simply hitting the MediaWiki API page. They cover dbpedia, a Java API, or the Special:Export function. They also make clear that the MediaWiki API is enabled on Wikipedia, which the page itself doesn't. So in short, the answers provide *a lot* of value that just googling wouldn't.

Comment: And you'd think the sheer number of upvotes on both the question and the answers are pretty strong evidence that googling was not sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

If that question were asked today it would be closed as off-topic because:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

It is off-topic because it's asking us to find an off-site resource, namely the Wikipeia API. It should not be unlocked. A lot of pages link to it, so we don't want to just delete it, but it is off-topic, so we don't want it to attract other similar questions. Locked is the best state for it to stay in.

Comment: In this case, the OP *did* "describe the problem*. And asking "is there an API" is really stretching the definition of asking for a recommendation. It's not asking "has anyone ever written a library to do X", it's saying "does this site itself provide an API".

Comment: @SteveBennett I didn't say that it's asking for a recommendation. I said it's asking us to *find* an off-site resource. That's off-topic too.

Comment: Isn't it essentially asking the same thing as these 6550 qusetions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=programmatically That is, "I want to do X using code, is that possible?"

Comment: @SteveBennett No, those questions are asking how to do something. The question you're asking about just wants someone to find an API for them. Look at the answers to that question. They're a bunch of links to APIs and docs. Do we need more answers like that?

Comment: Surely this is exactly the same thing, only a worse question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @SteveBennett No, that's an awful question, but it's not the same thing. Please don't post more 5 year old questions here. I don't have time to audit them all. Just use your close votes.