# How do I ask for resources without my question getting removed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, rules, recommendation-questions

So as you know there is a rule which states:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

However, sometimes I ask a perfectly fine question with code and the problem but would also like people to provide any references/resources/books/tools or whatever they have knowledge of that can solve the problem. Is this fine?

If not, is there a way to indirectly ask for good resources or should I just trust the answer to hopefully provide some links/references?

Comment: You are asking the community to be a crowd sourced search engine. There are many good non-crowd sourced search engines out there. There are sites dedicated to discussions and polling rather than Q&A focused on problems.  From Programmers.SE's meta a bit more on the aspect of asking for recommendations and that site's interpretation of this custom close reason: [Why was my question closed as off topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6487/)

Comment: Related [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/1595451)

Comment: The short answer is: you don't.

Answer (score 10):

These kinds of questions are not allowed because they attract spam and are typically opinion based. In its current state, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask for programming tools and recommendations.

The way around it is right there in the close reason:

> Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

It is often the case that you do not need a tool at all to solve your problem. Instead of trying to work your way around the actual problem by asking for an off-site resource, ask what is really at the root of your problem; why do you *need* that off-site resource?

Comment: Suppose somebody asks a question like "I have to research and report on XYZ. I need pointers." (where XYZ is extremely exotic and Google doesn't find anything relevant - happened to me). The problem is specifically that of gathering links/pointers, and it doesn't ask for opinions. Link-only answers may be perfectly valid ones. Personal opionions would not be valid answers. Creating a separate SO for such questions is IMO not good, since it wouldn't reach the domain ppl. A case by case analysis by mods, and decision by voting would IMO be better (although maybe not feasible).

Comment: @user625488 That's why those types of questions would be closed as "too broad."

Comment: I think a question about a domain so narrow that even Google can't find relevant links hardly qualifies as too broad.

But OK, I'm in no way involved in operating SO, and after having dug some more into Q&A about what SO is and what questions are meant to be, I can also see purpose in not allowing any kind of question.

What SO could do better is communicate what it is and what it's not. Its Q&A format only allows for very targeted, down to earth, hands-on knowledge to be shared. That's not obvious to new users or to people landing on SO from Google.

Comment: @user625488 *The problem is specifically that of gathering links/pointers" - Not at SO, it isn't. The fact you can't find anything via Google or Bing does not change an inappropriate question to appropriate. We're not anyone's personal research assistant, and this isn't a site for solving your personal problem. This has been discussed several previous times both here and at [meta.se], and the consensus is that questions asking for lists or links or external resources are off-topic. There are other sites that are outside [se] that accomodate those types of questions. Ask there.