# Can I ask for code libraries and plugins on Stack Overflow, or is that better suited for Software Recommendations?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I'm wanting to find a plugin that provides a specific functionality. Not a full software product, but also not a code snippet. Should I ask this question on Stack Overflow, or on Software Recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions asking for software recommendations, including plugin and library recommendations, are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Such questions are usually closed with the following close reason.

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

That being said, answers that recommend libraries as a solution to a problem can be on-topic. Here is where I would draw the distinction.

If there is a specific problem you are trying to solve, you could ask a question about that specific problem, and your attempted solution. Perhaps you do not need a plugin or library after all, or if you do, someone may recommend one as part of the solution.

If you are not facing a specific issue, but are instead looking for a plugin or library to provide some functionality (as appears to be your case), your question is probably better suited for Software Recommendations. Just be sure to read [their FAQ on what is on-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That's a good distinction - whether you're just looking for a solution to a problem and willing to accept plugin/library answers, or you know you need a plugin/library and you're looking specifically for that.