# Edit the software-rec close reason to include APIs / services

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

This is the current 'software recommendation' off-topic close reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254394/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

I often find myself using this reason to close "what API does X, Y, and Z" questions, specifically Internet-based APIs (like the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com) or a weather API). However, it doesn't seem to really fit:

- APIs *could* be tools, but that seems forced. "Tools" make me think of IDEs, regex testers, etc.
- APIs really aren't libraries
- 'favorite off-site resource' makes me think of 'resources' - fonts, images, tutorials, books, etc.

APIs are really *services*, even if they're free. Could we add this to the reason, ending with something like this?

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library, service or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254394/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: What kind of API are you talking about?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I should have made that clear - I'm thinking of weather APIs, the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com), etc. I'll edit to make it clear.

Comment: Yay, edit it and make **another** dup close reason ID.

Comment: Isn't an internet based API an off-site resource? Seems to fit just fine.