# Allow software tool recommendations for niche purposes?

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions

Software tool / library recommendations for common application scenarios (e.g. CSV parsing) are for good reasons considered off-topic on stackoverflow as they tend to result more into opinion polls than answers (e.g. [CSV API for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)).

For very niche / non-common application scenario's where it is in doubt whether a single software tool or library even exists for the task, the risk of turning into an opinion poll can be regarded as very low. At the same time, such questions might potentially save other users who have been elaborately searching google for the tool / library that does the specific thing that they need a lot of time. Of course there is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but it doesn't nearly have the userbase that stackoverflow has and many questions seem to stay unanswered.

Aren't we missing out on potentially interesting questions/answers by also regarding the niche / non-common kind of recommendation questions as off-topic on stackoverflow?

A concrete example of such a nice / non-common recommandation question is this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197556/multinomial-test-in-java, which I posted on stackoverflow earlier today and got classified as off-topic. Extensive googling in this case did not provide a library that performs the task requested, but that does not necessarily mean that no such library exists. It does mean however that there is definitely no plethora of such libraries, and the risk of an opinion poll type of answer section is therefore near zero.

(Note that I did not post this out of bitterness of my stackoverflow question being put on hold, I have no problem with that. I was just curious about your ideas on this topic.)

Comment: "Of course there is http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but it doesn't nearly have the userbase that stackoverflow has and many questions seen to stay unanswered. " - That's a poor reason to make it on topic here.

Comment: Who will draw the line between niche-enough-to-qualify and too-mainstream-to-be-useful?

Comment: @deceze:  [I think they're trying to, at least.](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: @Makoto Doesn't look like the same kind of line they're trying to draw.

Comment: @deceze:  I misinterpreted your question.  That's a much tougher distinction to draw.

Comment: @deceze A rule-of-thumb could be to flag as off-topic when you know two or more libraries that perform the task. Of course this will result in less people flagging the off topic flag, but the stackoverflow community is large enough to still keep the site clean from off-topic questions. I agree that it is a thin line, but it is not unmanageable.

Comment: It needs to be known *in advance* whether a question will be closed or not based on clear rules. After-the-fact-voting is not a way to define rules. What if three answers are posted, each proposing a different library. *Now* I know two or more libraries... may I close?

Comment: @deceze that is a very strong point. You convinced me.

Comment: _many questions seen to stay unanswered_ - Many of their questions are asking for something to do many things, do something difficult, work on an unusual or old platform, and/or are **free**. I think that often the thing the Asker is looking for doesn't actually exist, but it's rarely possible to prove that. Another thing that happens is that when someone isn't confident their answer is a true solution, it gets posted as a comment instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yup! Go right ahead and ask questions about solving your niche problem. Just don't ask for a tool; instead, **[describe the specific problem you're trying to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question/254394#254394)!**

> For a library, you know what you want to accomplish, and you've
>   presumed that finding a library that does it is the best solution -
>   but without knowing if one even exists, that's an invalid assumption.
>
> So just ask how you should do what you want to do, and leave the
>   library recommendations - if any - to the answerers.

Wanna know how to perform a multinomial test using Java? **Then ask that!** Don't assume there's a library; for all you know, it's two lines of code using only the standard frameworks. If a library *is* necessary or useful, someone will probably recommend one - but limiting answers to that **isn't necessary**, and tends to lead to bad behaviors *even in niche topics.*

Answer (score 7):

> Of course there is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but it doesn't nearly have the userbase that stackoverflow has and many questions seen to stay unanswered.

That is a poor reason to make it on topic here. These types of questions are off topic on Stack Overflow and on topic on Software Recs. Software Recs has a set of [guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) to follow for high quality posts. Their purpose is to suggest software. Stack Overflow purpose is not.

Answer (score 4):

In all fairness, Software Recs is a new site (having existed for a bit over a year), so I wouldn't expect it to have the same traffic as a site like Stack Overflow.

In fact, *no site* in the network compares to Stack Overflow in terms of size.

That said, the point of Stack Overflow isn't recommendations or what software to use to solve a problem.  The very nature of it is entirely too broad, as picking a library to solve your problem is painting the problem with a very wide brush.

You're welcome to give your question a try on Software Recs, but it wouldn't work out on Stack Overflow.