# Do we as a community value creating on-hold dead-end questions over helpful information?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderation

Today I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795713/creating-ascii-packet-diagrams-as-in-rfc) when searching for a tool I had previously used, but couldn't remember the name. The question is exactly what I was looking for. It even had the *answer* I was looking for, though deleted. I couldn't see why this had been deleted, so I flagged it for mod attention. Now the answer is *still* deleted, and the question is on-hold.

I understand, to a certain degree, why the question was put on hold. I don't agree with it, but so be it. But I can not understand what value there is in putting the question on-hold without un-deleting the valid answer to it. The current outcome is that there is a dead-end question with a valid, deleted answer, that people will run into and be sad that nobody has provided anything useful.

What is the benefit of putting this question on-hold without at least un-deleting the answer?

Comment: Related: [Allow software tool recommendations for niche purposes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294130)

Comment: If those recommendations answers are not deleted, is much harder to actually delete this off-topic questions. And the question is off-topic... why wouldn't it be put on-hold?

Comment: That is just standard bot misery at work.  Such a post gets detected by the Natty bot as "late answer to old question", default follow-up is often to delete the post instead of using the "convert to comment" option.  And not look at the question, deleting questions creates a lot of upheaval that SO mods tend to prefer to avoid.  Whether document creation tools are on topic is pretty questionable.  You could DV the question but I'm guessing you are not exactly in the mood for that right now :)

Comment: @HansPassant it is [**NATO**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=46179713&room=126814) New Answers To Old questions. Just fyi so you can express your distaste of it correctly next time ;)

Comment: Hmm, [it says Natty in the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/126814?m=39109058#39109058).  Well, more things to dislike about it I guess.

Comment: @Hans AFAIK Natty (which is the name of the bot, NATO refers to the original New Answers To Old questions page of the 10k tools as well as the steady stream of posts matching the given criteria that the bot posts in the chatroom) only posts links to questions matching a given criteria in the chatroom, and flags any that cross a given threshold for moderator attention. I don't believe that the bot has the ability to delete anything. Dont blame the bot that is identifying the posts for review. Thats like blaming the heuristics in the LQPRQ for users incorrectly deleting content there.

Comment: possibly related: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Comment: @TinyGiant But Hans' comment *did* blame the users' follow up, not the bot itself.

Comment: @Servy I must have missed the mention of users amidst all of the references to the bot. Would you mind pointing out where Hans lays blame on the users reviewing the posts identified by the bot? Or even better yet, let Hans handle the clarification of who or what he was intending to lay the blame on in his commentary here.

Answer (score 6):

The benefit of putting the question on hold is that the question author, and the rest of the community, becomes aware that the question is not appropriate for the site.  The question author (or potentially other users, although often the question author is needed) can improve the question to address the problem(s) with it, allowing it to be reopened.

Closing the question also allows other community members to see that the question isn't appropriate, without even needing to open up the question.  This means that users won't need to waste their time reviewing the question unless they specifically go in with the intent of helping the author improve a problematic question.

Finally, closing the question provides a path for deletion should the question not be improved after some time.  Given both the age and degree of problems with this question, this seems rather likely in this situation, although in other situations the path towards fixing the question will be more realistic.