# Is this question about active directory okay to be asked on SO

Tags: discussion

I graduated and started working for this company who let graduates develop very important modules or layers that evolves around application.

I would like to know how people design there Active Directory module using .Net (e.g. do they create a WCF service and host it on AD server (I read about it somewhere) or do they create a .net library to access AD from application server).

ATM we are using a library developed by ex developer which is deployed on application server and it is sometimes slow and also has duplicate code.

Also would it be legal to ask if anyone knows a library there to be used to query AD already.

I am not sure if these questions would be legal or off topic or opinion based, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those questions sounds more as whiteboard discussions rather than an actual programming question. That makes them off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you can detail the design question enough you might want to check on the meta of [Programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if that question would fly on their site.

Also asking for a library is a so called shopping question and these are also not a good fit. They even have their own close reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Shopping questions are banned across the Stack Exchange network. Within very strict rules some will work on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but their [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) are the most strict. Your question as stated *Does anyone know a library to be used to query AD* will not be accepted on Software Recommendations.