# Parse.com is shutting down and SO is flooded with off-topic requests for alternatives

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

[parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse.com) is shutting down at the end of the year, and Stack Overflow is getting flooded with off topic questions asking for alternatives (more than 11 in the last 8 hours). Some are already closed, some not, some are upvoted some downvoted.

What is the best course of action here, besides close voting and down voting.

Flagging questions for additional mod attention?

If flagging for mod attention is appropriate, should I save my close votes or cast them anyway?

---

Just for illustration what I mean by flood, comparing to usual situation:

- All questions are basically the same - *What is Parse alternative?*
- Users asking those questions are by no means fresh *just joined today* users
- Amount of those off-topic questions comparing to regular ones in tag is unusual

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was more than 11, a lot were deleted, and more keep coming (just VTC-ed another one).

Comment: @Paulie_D I am afraid it is just beginning. Almost every second new question in parse.com tag is now totally off topic.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am not asking for magical parser. I am asking if flagging questions for mod attention would be appropriate since, this seems like extraordinary situation. And, yes, I am aware of number of questions (including bad ones) asked every day.

Comment: consider asking folks in [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room to keep an eye on parse related tags

Comment: 11 in 8 hours is not exactly a flood, nor is it in any way extraordinary.

Comment: I closevote as tool request & respond with: _"Please don't ask for alternatives to discontinued tools. Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's more than that, and it's all the same question: _"I want an alternative, help!"_. That's extraordinary.

Comment: @Cerbrus: It's not extraordinary; that happens _tens of times every day_ for many tags on SO. Just dig in, close vote, and move on. And if you don't want to, leave it to someone else to do!

Comment: How can there be *any* on-topic, properly-tagged new questions regarding parse.com if they shut down? Or is that still a few month in the future?

Comment: @Deduplicator: they'll shut down in about a year. So, there _can_ be on-topic questions. (There are)

Comment: "questions asking for parse.com alternatives" might be suitable for software recommendation stackexchange. I would suggest to the askers to ask there instead of here where they are clearly off topic and should be closed.

Comment: And there are others not in the [tag:parse.com] asking similar things

Comment: @Trilarion you should check with Software Recommendations people first, and make sure that you only suggest this to askers who ask better-than-crap questions. [Sister sites are understandably grumpy when we channel our own crap to them](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). (I know, different site, but they found it worth while to add a FAQ about migrating from SO.)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'm a bit active on Software Rec too. If you would count me as one of their people I would be able to do the check myself which would save some time. I knew about their grumpiness and the reasons behind it but I hope that everyone also respects the freedom of comments. A real double check is not strictly necessary for comments and there is also the chance for a genuine Software Rec question (especially for a particular close reason on SO). Here: an alternative for parse.com, I think, could be a high quality Software Rec question. It's definitely not crap.

Comment: @Trilarion my comment was more of a general warning: unlike you I'm not active there:) I even checked your profile, but didn't realize that you were active on a few dozen sites, sorry. I just wanted to warn you (and especially others) to be careful in general, since I used to be one of the "send everybody to codereview"-offenders.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Okay, in this case thanks for the general warning. I think in this case there is not much to worry but in general I think that experience with the target site definitely helps when recommending to ask there. People should only recommend something if they already used it and know how it works.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), we're aware of this situation (in fact we already edited the [parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse.com) wiki to reflect this change) and have been discussing it. We were discussing whether we have one as a [dupe target](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28432848#28432848) and close the others as dupes, but a lack of suitable dupe target lead us to close them as off-topic on the merits of each question, though this is not set in stone.

We'll be monitoring the site for these questions, but if you find one about this, feel free to post a link to it in the room. There will be plenty of people willing to review the question. If you have close votes then casting a close vote is always helpful on an off topic question.

As has been mentioned elsewhere here, mod flagging is not needed; the community can handle this, and by community, I mean all of us and we don't want to overload mods with flags that are unnecessary.

Comment: I know you can't close as dupe unless a question has an answer, but I'm pretty sure you can close a question as a dupe of another closed question (unless they changed that :/ ).  So all you need is one of these with an answer and use that as the canonical.  It won't be perfect, but anybody with a gold tag on the question can instahammer it closed.

Comment: @Will the thing is, there is an automated process that deletes questions that are closed given certain rules.. and this doesn't work on dupes, so there is an advantage to not closing as a dupe.

Comment: The advantage is that it's a little bit easier to delete them if they happen to be upvoted, @MsYvette (if they're downvoted or 0-scored they'll get cleaned up automatically eventually anyway). The disadvantage is that it's harder to find the "target" question if there aren't any questions pointing to it, which makes it more likely folks will ask new ones. Also not great is that without a dup-target you don't get dup-hammer closing from folks with gold badges in related tags (iOS and Android have plenty).

Answer (score 50):

I can appreciate that a 'flood' of bad or off-topic questions can be frustrating but..

**NO**

Flagging for moderator action/attention wouldn't be appropriate...Downvoting and Closevoting would.

Moderators only need to be involved if the community voting tools won't cover the matter...which they do.

Just dig in..

Answer (score 23):

> If flagging for mod attention is appropriate, should I save my close
>   votes or cast them anyway?

No, moderator attention is only appropiate for when the community cannot reasonably handle an issue on its own. These questions are classic cases of vote to close / downvote / vote to delete and move on.

Answer (score 4):

> Some are already closed, some not, some are upvoted some downvoted.

If you let everybody vote, chances are that people vote based on gut feeling, or the amount of clouds in the sky, or whether their favorite keyword is present in the post. In other words: not all votes are objective and informed.

With the current, massive Stack Overflow population, it is impossible to reach consensus anymore. What happens to a post depends on which users happen to read it.

There's nothing you can do about it, but vote appropriately as *you* seem fit.

Comment: Nonsense. Not all posts get the same amount of visitors. This is a visibility issue, not a democracy issue.

Comment: @Cerbrus if you want to discuss something, not starting your reply with "nonsense" would help there. Are you denying that Stack Overflow users have their personal motives for voting? I think what you say supports my claim: it depends on which users see your question. One votes up, the other votes down.

Comment: My comment was more about the "Democracy" part of your answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus the end result of democracy (_"everybody gets to vote"_) is that the end result, or the application of those votes, is rather, eh, average.

Comment: Ah, yes. Democracy is the worst system, aside from all the others.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't want to go into too much detail in comments here, but **maybe** it isn't that good an idea that everybody can vote on everything. I see the "like"-pattern emerge more and more, where the most atrocious of questions get upvoted because they contain an "interesting" term like "sockets", "3D game" or "image processing". It's a discussion question, yes? This is my view, just vote accordingly.

Comment: That's not democracy. That's anarchy.

Comment: @CodeCaster couldn't agree with you more... I have been thinking, I must post a question with `binary` and a few other keywords and see what happens

Comment: @MsYvette _"I want to store the binary data of an image for shape recognition for my 3D game in a web-scale cloud database and read them through websockets, please help"_ **+42**

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, that sums up the downsides very well. Unfortunately, it's a bit difficult to algorithmically determine who *knows* the stuff. Might be easier if we actually purged all the bad content somewhat reliably, instead of sporadically and sparsely. Anything in that direction gets killed by the "feel-good-crowd" on meta though.

Comment: @Deduplicator reliably closing less than perfect questions _and_ meanwhile guiding the OP towards asking a better question would be an ultimate goal. Far from reality, though. Lots of users don't really care about "shoveling crap" off the site and beating the content already on it into better shape, they just want to post answers.

Comment: @Deduplicator You already know. Reputation. Just raise the bar for close votes or whatever.

Comment: High rep = voting rights? Hmm, where have a seen a similar scenario? Only someone with lots of rep would put forth the notion that voting should require higher rep. Sure, not everyone votes the way we would all like but voting is inherently subjective so who cares. Why not just get rid of rep and de-gamify the site if it hurts so many butts?

Comment: @Chief nowhere am I advocating for that, don't put words in my mouth. The point of voting is indicating quality, and that is not at all how it's currently used, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to put words in your mouth. I was responding to "...[maybe isn't good that everybody can vote]..." Reading it again I can see that I may have implied you directly proposed voting restrictions by rep; you didn't. I was basing that on the fact the site is restricted by rep and seems to be the way to keep users from doing certain things; I can't see any other way to restrict voting. I agree with you on how voting's used now but that's the nature of "one man one vote."(!=quality) Point is, they're subjective and valid to the voter and no one would suppress their *own* votes.

Comment: @Chief it's ok. _If_ voting were to be limited, I would like it to be linked to _experience_, which is inherently hard to qualify. Maybe there is no solution to truly rank posts on quality.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I'd also like to point out that [15 rep for upvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) is veeeery low. Imagine a hypothetical scenario: "Oh, look, new user, how cute, +1!", and then "Yikes, what a crap question! Oh, it's a new user...pity the fool. +1!" and then we very quickly duplicate the problem in a user who might be entirely clueless about the workings of the site, and very happy with everyone coming their way. I way too often go "*whyyyy is this upvoted?"...

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I agree; I earned 2x that [in 20 mins](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1361787/chieftwopencils?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2016-01-29%2005:13:40Z&page=13) my first day (with a question of questionable quality no less). The converse of your scenario is also real tho. There're users with 30k+ rep having only answered one question ages ago that's well below today's quality standards. They now have many powers including one click closures. So I don't find rep a good indicator of quality participation tho ideally it would/should.