# Is it valid to ask for recommended a tool when I can not find one

Tags: discussion, scope

Is this kind of question valid?

> I need a tool that help with "xxxx" while debugging in "yyyyy" IDE. I
>   was using "zzzzz". However, it is not working anymore due to "tttttt".
>   I could not find any alternative. So I am basically asking for any
>   working one not asking for the best one in your opinion.

P.S. I think there is no other one. If there is, I do not think there will be more than one. So I feel that this question is valid. Isn't it?

Comment: Nope, SO doesn't do resource recommendations at all any more because they tend to attract many bad answers and spam.

Comment: Even when you think there is no more than 1 choice ?

Comment: You can try [Sotware Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to read their help center before posting!

Comment: "it is not working anymore" is part of the whole reason why they're not allowed, this alone proves that an answer may not be useful to future readers

Comment: Just present the problem you have now, do not assume at all that you need to go shopping or that only "best" will do.  Fwiw, I've yet to encounter a question where somebody asked for the worst :)  Always high odds that you'll find somebody that encountered the same problem and has either found a workaround for it or will provide you with a tooling recommendation.  Picking the right tags is important, don't make them too broad.  The IDE's [tag] is fine, something like [java] is not.

Comment: I see. Thanks for all of you:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions like that are **off-topic** for SO.

There is a closure reason specifically for cases like this:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

As [Cool Guy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy) mentioned, you can try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Just make sure to follow their rules & guidelines.