# Why has someone suggested my new mysql question get closed?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101653/mysql-innodb-tables-with-autoincrement-id-columns

I only raised the question an hour or so ago and I note that one person has suggested the request be closed. No comments, nothing. I've checked my reputation and other available info in my profile but I cannot trace rhyme or reason for this. If I've done something wrong, I would correct it once I was more clear.

thanks...

Comment: It was closed because you're asking for off site resources. Instead of doing that, ask how to solve your specific issue. From a practical standpoint, you're making things hard on yourself and the database engine by not using its ID columns. The database was built by people much smarter than you or I, don't try to outthink them.

Answer (score 7):

The first close voter choose this reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

and a moderator followed suit.

The following sentence probably caused that:

> If you can direct me towards a MySQL man page which discusses this, I would appreciate it

Overall your question seems too broad and/or opinion based. You need to describe why your current design and implementation isn't working. Besides that your question seems also to ask several sub-questions. Just try to stick to one question at a time.

You might find the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) useful to check if your question meets the most general quality criteria.

Comment: I find that decision harsh. I was expecting someone to direct me to a mysql man page that would assist the answer.

Comment: We're an answer service, not a redirection service @fiprojects. If there's any hint that you're just looking for a manual/links/etc, it's the wrong sort of question for Q+A. You should be asking a single, specific question, that hopefully has a single, specific answer, which lives _here_, not somewhere else. Just keep that in mind when you ask and you'll be golden

Comment: I'm disappointed with @Clive answer for two reasons... firstly, the least up to date answer will be found in any place other than the original source. While stackoverflow is good, very good even, preventing someone from directing a reader to the source/reference page of a command is unhelpful. This leads me to my second reason why your answer is a surprise... When logging on to StackOverflow, it does say "Stack Overflow is a community of 4.7 million programmers, just like you, helping each other."  The "...helping each other..." is what brought me here in the first place...

Comment: Yes, I like to help users like you @fiprojects hence my answer here so you get some guidance and explanation what might be the issue with your question. That you don't like that outcome is understandable but not something I can or will fix.

Comment: @fiprojects It's a subtle difference so anyone can be forgiven for missing it, but thinking that we're _preventing someone from directing a reader to the source/reference page of a command_ is where you're going wrong. You're concentrating on the wrong thing - what we don't want are _questions_ that ask for links to manuals, because history and experience has shown that these devolve into the wrong thing for Q+A. _Answers_ that both show an example, and link to the docs for reference, are actually ideal, and what we do want

Comment: It sounds like nitpicking, but you have to understand these rules haven't just been dreamt up - they're the result of years of the staff and community fine-tuning how they want things to work

Comment: @Clive Your one sentance above, which I quote *Answers that both show an example, and link to the docs for reference, are actually ideal, and what we do want* sounds helpful/positive and what I am glad to read. Thanks.