# Duplicate question to recommend approach, asked 5 years later

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436300/query-frameworks-in-web-api-or-wcf is faily obviously a duplicate of this one [Are there any alternatives to OData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391236/are-there-any-alternatives-to-odata).

However, the duplicated question was asked in 2011. Since then it is entirely possible that, as the OP of the duplicate has pointed out, alternatives to OData do now exist.

I'm confused as to what to do.

Comment: You could make the argument that both should be closed as recommendation questions

Comment: The fate of such "has anything changed?" questions is usually to get no answer.  From which it could be inferred that, no, probably not, although you can never be sure.  SO just isn't a very good place to get a "no" answer.  Maybe an answer will show up five years from now, not unlikely to be project spam.  Not good Q+A, feel free to vote.

Comment: 16k, not sure what is on topic, mfw

Answer (score 2):

It might be a duplicate but both questions should be closed by today standards for the off-topic reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

That solves the debate about which duplicate target is better as well.