# Support for question

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, specific-question, recommendation-questions

I recently asked the question [The Definitive Python Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396265/the-definitive-python-book-guide-and-list) without knowing that it requires support to ask such questions. So here I am for support.

Reason to ask (from the question):

> Python is becoming an important language. It is incredibly powerful, broad yet simple. Python is quite good language for Scripting and Data Analysis. Python is often the language recommended and used to teach beginners programming language. Hence there are a lot of python books available. And as a consequences there are very bad Python books out there. They not only have bad style but also promote bad programming styles.
>
> The beginning stages of programming are crucial and set the course for the future coding. Though practices can be changed in the future but prevention is better than cure.

This is pretty constructive I suppose. We need to have a definitive guide. I have also posted in [the Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). Please support this.

Comment: *"We need to have a definitive guide"* - that doesn't mean it has to be *here*.

Comment: Look, what would happen if I posted as an answer: 'Nobody cares.  Python is an annoying irrelevance with bad syntax and ridiculous libraries.  We don't need any more books on such trash, just a can of gas and a match'?

Answer (score 7):

You seem to have some misunderstandings about how this site works. Questions like that don't "require support." They're simply 100% off-topic. There's no special permission that you can get to post that question; you simply can't post it.

Your question was closed with this reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

The site is not going to "support" creation of lists like this. For the reasons above (and actually many more), questions asking for off-site resources are *not* constructive. They actually tend to turn into unmaintained (and unmaintainable) piles of outdated and spammy links. Worse, they do so very quickly. They never fit the site's goal of presenting (1) a clear, specific question about a specific programming problem and (2) all information necessary to answer it on a single page. The site does *not* attempt to create definitive lists of off-site resources.

So, that question was simply off-topic. It will and should remain closed.