# How do I find my permanently deleted question? And why was my question deleted?

Tags: support

I have posted a question on Stack Overflow regarding the library for annotating structural documents in Python a while ago. My question collected no answers for a while. A week ago, somebody downvoted it. I reacted with a comment, asking to explain the reason. Now the question has disappeared. The question and its comment is not present in my account history. The badge for the unanswered question is gone. No reputation change is recorded. I can not find any reference to it.

Dear administrators, how do I see the text of the question again? And why was it deleted so permanently?

I would like to note that such deliberate disregard for intellectual property makes me rethink about discussing my ideas on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Badge for unanswered question is gone." - You mean [this tumbleweed badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=1721985) listed in your profile? Doesn't *seem* "gone".

Comment: It's not clear why you think there's an IP issue here. You retain the right to publish your content elsewhere, but you aren't entitled to free web hosting on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33965345/needed-python-framework-module-to-annotate-text-document-producing-an-html

It was deleted [automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) as it was quite old, unanswered and scored < 0. In general, [library-requests are discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question); if you decide to self-answer at some point, I recommend structuring it as a "How do I..." question rather than a request for a framework.

Comment: how do I locate such questions?

Comment: @MikhailNZakharov You don't; you need to already have a link to them to get there.  Or I guess you could run and get elected as a mod, and then you could search for them.