# Can almost same questions be regarded as spam?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, spam

Is it spam, when four questions are asked almost simultaneously with only a change of title and first sentence?

[image]

Comment: I usually flag for moderator attention when a user does this and include links to all the questions.

Comment: Damnit, Gary...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, it is not [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) (it's not advertising anything), but all these questions are off-topic. You can flag them to be closed as a recommendation request:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Incidentally, his questions look like Topic Requests in the new Documentation feature of the site. So you might place a comment asking the author to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/topics).

Answer (score 26):

**Spam** is an unsolicited advertisement or undisclosed self-promotion. These posts are neither of those things; hence, they are not spam.

The **abusive** flag may be used in cases where a user consistently repeats an identical or almost-identical question over and over. Again, this is not the case here - each question is asking about something different, even if the wording is similar.

What these are, are *misguided* questions. They're not on-topic here, so vote or flag to close them. They are also low-quality, so you can use a Very Low Quality flag on them to send them to the Low Quality Posts review queue for closure and subsequent deletion.

Comment: I consider it abuse to use a form question that has nothing at all to do with the topic except where one word is inserted.  Questions are supposed to show the poster's previous effort and understanding, and he hasn't done so.  When he went from posting one badly-researched question to turning it into a template for cookie-cutter bad questions, he crossed the line into intentional misbehavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt Assume good faith. Some people just don't know what's on-topic here or that we don't like cookie cutters. And sure, they should have researched it, but we live in the real world, where they *don't*.

Comment: This is a pretty clear-cut case of abuse. They've literally pasted the same question over and over, *modifying no more than 2 words*. They are certainly "misguided" questions, but they're also abusive questions. They are abusive of both the community and our resources.

Comment: That's not exactly the definition of "spam", it's just the one that SE accepts, which is confusing to some and annoying to others. SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM SPAMMY SPAM SPAM

Comment: @Will Indeed. I'd flag a post like that as abusive instead.

Comment: @Will As stated in other places on meta that is a prime candidate from rude/abusive as it is not something you would do in a respectful discourse.

Comment: "Spamming" a newsgroup, forum, or other site is used for the advertising type, but also for quickly adding one post after another. On Stack Overflow, the "This is spam" flag seems reserved for the first meaning; for this, the second meaning, it's indeed 'rude/abusive'.