# Voting to Close as "Recommendation" When No Recommendation Has been Asked For

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

Recently, I have seen quite a few "gimme teh codez" questions being voted-to-close as off-topic "recommendation questions" (most recent example that I have seen is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039883/find-a-word-from-a-string). It is currently on hold as "too broad", but the first two votes on it were "recommendation").

The description for the flag clearly highlights that it is to be used for *recommendations*:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Even the first sentence of the accepted answer in the question linked in the description says:

> "Recommendation question" is shorthand for "you didn't describe a problem, you just asked for a list of things."

This seems to agree with my interpretation that the "recommendation" flag is to be used for questions asking for a library, tutorial site, etc.

*However...*

The second sentence of the flag's description says the question should be describing the asker's problem and attempts. I can *almost* see this as justification to use this flag, even in cases where the asker clearly states the problem but has put no effort into a solution, but I don't think it really fits in with the spirit of the bolded part of the description.

So, is this proper usage of that flag/close vote?

Comment: Obviously a couple of people thought the OP was asking for a tutorial and voted accordingly. The **important** thing is...it got closed.

Comment: The question was closed for a perfectly fine reason.  There's no real problem here.  If you find questions actually closed for an improper reason *then* it's potentially something to bring up.

Comment: I could go through my history and find some, but there were a few this week that I saw actually (improperly in my opinion) get closed as recommendation.

Comment: If some people legitimately interpret "here's what I want to do, please help" as looking for tutorials, then I can't disagree with them voting that way. I just don't see it that way and was wondering if it's right or wrong to vote that way.

Comment: Analogy time? [Improving "demonstrate a minimal understanding" close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220)

Comment: I _suppose_ it could be seen as a tutorial request, in the sense that the OP doesn't know what to do and therefore needs a tutorial. However, (AFAICT) the "recommendation" close reason is intended to apply to pre-written off-site tutorials, not to a fresh tutorial written as an answer. Questions that need a tutorial-style answer tend to be too broad, unless it's very clear what the OP needs to know. Another option here is "unclear", since the OP hasn't actually asked a question, and it's impossible to give specific help without further information from the OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "Recommendation question" is like asking for a shopping list. It could, potentially, be answered with a list of links to various books, libraries, or tutorials.

A "too broad" question, which this was closed as, usually needs large blocks of code or a chapter in a book to effectively answer. Another indication of "too broad" is when the user describes a problem but never actually asks a question - which is what happened in this case.

There are several ways this user's task could be accomplished, but we don't know what they have tried or where they have failed. Are they using natural language processing? Are they using RegEx? Are they parsing for certain key words? There is no indication of what the user has done or tried.

Knowledge of the problem domain can impact how you vote. If you know that this can be solved using a specific library (an NLP library, perhaps), you may cast a vote with the recommendation close reason. If you aren't aware of the problem domain, but know there are tutorials out there, you may cast a recommendation close vote. Others may not be aware of either, and simply cast "too broad".

The important thing to take away from this, is that the question was closed. It is not a good question for Stack Overflow. "Too broad" is a good reason for it to be closed, and the close reason displayed to the 1 rep user is entirely appropriate. This is a broad question.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought about questions being viewed that way. Would I be correct to continue flagging as too broad (where appropriate) instead of recommendation? I don't know if questions still get closed at 5 votes even if they're all different, but I can't bring myself to follow what everyone else is doing just to get it closed if I don't agree with the reason.

Comment: @jonhopkins Pick whatever you want. Close votes are close votes; a question gets 5 of any type, the question is closed.