# Request to reopen question on 'eBay API call implementation' which has been marked as off-topic

Tags: discussion, support, reopen-closed

My question [How do I dump “Custom Shipping Rate Tables” for an eBay seller, based off ID or Auth Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009783/how-do-i-dump-custom-shipping-rate-tables-for-an-ebay-seller-based-off-id-or) has been marked as off-topic and hence got closed.

The question has been edited and hopefully it is now answerable and can be reopened.

Comment: Beware of the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) (And it's still off-topic IMO)

Comment: Note that simply editing the question moves it to a "Reopen Queue" where people will review the question and vote on whether it is eligible for reopening. See the final paragraph in https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions.

Comment: @AlonEitan, I fail to understand why my question is considered as off-topic when there are many similar questions on Stack Overflow such as [Amazon Api: get order refund status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278551/amazon-api-get-order-refund-status), [Get refund status from amazon mws order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560099/get-refund-status-from-amazon-mws-order) etc. I am sure there might be many more.

Comment: @Sam Questions without [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are _usually_ closed as off-topic. One should include code in their question, this is not school, and people don't need to guess the OP level of knowledge or assume they tried their best before posting a LQ question. I VTC one of the question, and I'm not familiar in the field of the other one so I didn't take any action on that

Answer (score 5):

You have edited the question but still it is off topic. Because:

- You have not shown your effort.
- You are asking for the complete code that means a tool
- You don't specify a specific problem in that.

I will recommend you to [Read this Topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) before asking or editing the question and to ask for reopen.

Comment: Not showing effort isn't a reason to close (downvote yeah, but not close)

Comment: @CodeLover, I believe I have shown my effort by mentioning that I have already checked out some other API calls such as 'GetUser' and 'GetStore' and moreover I am only asking for specific API call or a function and not a complete tool. On top of that, I have also specified the problem that I am looking to dump 'Custom Shipping Rate Table' for an eBay seller.

Comment: *You are asking for the complete code that means a tool* - No, that means it's likely too broad. They're asking for an answer that might be too long for the site but they aren't asking for something that exists off site.