# What difference between these two questions caused just the one to be close-voted?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, asking-questions

I've been wondering for a while how one can find exactly what language specifiers work for syntax highlighting in GitHub Markdown, so last Friday I went and spent a few hours researching the topic, and when I wasn't able to find a complete, satisfactory solution, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45516228/5044950). There were already a few similar questions on Stack Overflow, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11568093/5044950) being the closest, but as I mentioned in the questions I asked, the scope of mine is a bit broader than the existing ones.

However, as far as I can tell, other than the level of research effort put into the two questions, the only other difference between the two is that mine asks for a way to find *all* valid keywords for a language, rather than just *a* valid keyword. Yet mine got a close vote with the reason

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

I'm having a bit of trouble seeing how my question falls under this category, since I'm not asking for an off-site resource; I'm essentially just asking how that `languages.yml` file works. **Is there an important difference between these two questions that I'm not seeing, which makes mine off-topic?** And if so, is there a way that I can change my question to be on-topic as that other one is?

Comment: I think mentioning the tool suggestions in those other posts worked against you here. "These tools exist but I'm skeptical" sounds too close to "suggest another tool" instead of "tell me how to do it myself".

Comment: @BSMP That makes sense. I wouldn't use the word "tool" myself, but I think I see your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Your question

> What I'm looking for is a way to get something like the list of language codes for Stack Exchange syntax highlighting, but for Markdown on GitHub. How can I get such a list?

## The other question

> How do I look up the specifier for a programming language? (e.g. C does not seem to work for the C programming language)

You're pretty explicitly asking for a list. The other question is asking where he can find the information. The latter *might not involve an off-site resource*. In fact an answer with a link and a copied list would be perfectly on-topic.

The key in questions like this is to ask it in such a way that someone who provides a link-only answer is providing a perfectly valid answer. Which, over time, [breaks down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Make the answer **give you the results** and not just **tell you where to find results**. If someone gives you the latter, flag it as Low Quality and it goes away.

So what I would do is change your question to something that asks this

> How can I make my program get valid markdown syntax for a given language?

Now you're asking for how to *write a program*, not a list of links. Answers can now contain links, but they must contain more than just that.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. So you're saying that my unfortunate phrasing gives the impression that I'm asking for a list (which would be an off-site resource), whereas what I'm _actually_ asking for is a _program_ to generate such a list, which would be on-topic but doesn't come across in the question as written?

Comment: I have modified my question to try to reflect my intention. Would you recommend any further changes?

Comment: I think that looks good. Voted to reopen

Answer (score 19):

It is arguable that the question you reference as being on-topic is actually
 an off-site resource request and should be closed as such. Interestingly, your question doesn't actually seem to be an off-site resource request; However, your question is still off-topic for multiple other reasons.

You're actually asking two different questions: a how-to question, and a debugging question, so I'm going to split them up.

**The How-To Question**:

> There is a [page on GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/#syntax-highlighting) describing how to use
>   syntax-highlighted code blocks. On that page there are instructions
>   describing how to match languages to their keywords for this purpose:
>
> > We use [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) to perform language detection and syntax highlighting. You can find out which keywords are valid in [the
> >     languages YAML file](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml).
>
> However, there's a lot of data in that YAML and I don't find it very
>   clear how exactly one can use it to determine which keywords work for
>   any given language.
>
> ...
>
> There are already some questions about this on Stack Overflow; [an
>   answer to one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11568417/5044950) mentions something called Pygments, while [an
>   answer to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11890935/5044950) mentions something called Garrett Flavored
>   Markdown. I'm skeptical about both of these; I can't tell whether
>   either of them are related to the Linguist library linked from the
>   Help page. In any case, all existing questions only ask for ways to
>   find *a* valid keyword for a given language, not *all* valid keywords.
>
> What I'm looking for is a way to get something like the [list of
>   language codes for Stack Exchange syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/297476), but for
>   Markdown on GitHub. **How can I get such a list?**

There are two ways this question can go and both are too broad the way the question is currently written; either:

1. You actually just want the list.

   Such a question would unequivocally not fit the Stack Exchange format, and would most likely never be allowed. If it were allowed to exist, it would have to be maintained any time the original list is changed, and I imagine there would be semi-regular meta arguments about such a post.
2. You want a solution to generate such a list programmatically.

   This is too broad for two main reasons:

   1. You haven't specified a language, you've only specified an output language (JSON). You haven't even specified the format of the output (the format can largely be assumed, but that is open for interpretation so it isn't helping you).
   2. Given the requirements of the current question, this is too broad to ever be useful to future viewers. You want to generate such a list from a very specific input, and no one else is going to want to generate the same output from that input.

      If you split up this task into its component parts, you get:

      - You need to parse the YAML using whatever programming language you pick to work with.
      - You need to interpret that parsed data into another format
      - You need to output the data to the client

      Ultimately, you can probably figure out how to parse the YAML using whatever programming language you pick to work with, and how to output the data to the client. This leaves you with the important question of how to interpret the parsed data into another format.

      Now you want have the makings of a reasonable how-to style question. To give your question the best chance possible, you're going to want to cut down on any ambiguities or uncertain terms, as well as cutting down on the application specific requirements that don't really matter.

      To do this, I'd recommend the following:

      - Figure out what language you're going to use.
      - Generate a generic example representing the parsed data that removes anything application specific and is as basic as possible while still representing the actual structure of the real data.
      - Figure out the exact output structure you want, and lay that out as simply as possible using a short description of the relationship between the input and the output, as well as an example of the output you would expect to be generated from the example input.
      - List all requirements clearly and concisely, removing any requirements that are not absolutely necessary.
      - Be sure to clearly and concisely ask how to go about getting the expected output from the example input while abiding by the minimal requirements that you've worked out.

      Once you've done all of that, you may find yourself the proud owner of an on-topic how-to style question.

**The Debugging Question**:

> I wrote a simple [boot](https://pastebin.com/MKdfDhfq) to attempt to parse this YAML to a
>   more readable [JSON](https://pastebin.com/GVnRw9Mn) file mapping from each language to its list of
>   valid keywords:
>
> ```sh
> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/linguist/f75c5707a62a3d66501993116826f4e64c3ca4dd/lib/linguist/languages.yml
> ```
>
> | ./languages.boot > languages.json
>
> But I'm not at all convinced that this is correct. For instance, many
>   of the keywords that my script produces include spaces, and I was
>   under the impression that [those would not work](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#info-string):
>
> > The content of a code fence is treated as literal text, not parsed as inlines. The first word of the [info string](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#info-string) is typically used to
> >     specify the language of the code sample, and rendered in the `class`
> >     attribute of the `code` tag.

This question is off-topic for most of the reasons listed under the "Debugging/No MCVE" close reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Your question does include the desired behavior and a specific problem (specificity arguable), but it *does not* include:

- The shortest code necessary to reproduce it (in the question itself).
- Example input (in the question itself).
- Expected output.

Namely, it does not include an MCVE.

If you were to edit the question to include an MCVE in the question itself which were to actually abide by the guidelines set forth in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e. not a huge code dump, nothing application specific that is unnecessary, etc.), then you may end up with an on-topic debugging style question.

Comment: That is not at all how I interpreted the How-To half.  It sounds to me like "this configuration file doesn't make much sense; if I wanted to use it, what does each key/etc mean and where are the keywords?" with the end result being able to extract the list.

Comment: `and I don't find it very clear how exactly one can use it to determine which keywords work for any given language.`

Comment: @TinyGiant The interpretation Izkata gives of my question is correct. How can I modify my question to more accurately reflect that intention? I admit that I don't understand your points under "You want a solution to generate such a list programmatically." - your recommendations seem to assume that what I ultimately want is a _concrete_ program that performs this task. This is not at all what I want...

Comment: ... rather, as Izkata said, I want to understand the meaning of the `languages.yml` file in this particular context, and I believe that the best way to _achieve_ that would be with a program that converts from the languages file to the a mapping from languages to keywords. The reason I haven't specified a programming language is that **I don't care what programming language** the solution is written in. It doesn't need to be written in a formal language at all; if some pseudocode gets the point across, so much the better.

Comment: This is also why I didn't include my source code and the expected output in my question: the specific source code is tangential to the question itself (I'm only using it for illustrative purposes and to demonstrate my research effort), and **I don't know what output to expect**, which is the entire point of the question. Given this, what would you suggest?