# Answer pointing to open-source library on question about library was deleted by a mod

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, moderators

**Background**:

I needed to consume Server-Sent Events from java, preferably with RxJava, for an Android application that I am developing.

Naturally, I turned to Google and to StackOverflow to find if such solution existed.

While looking for this, I saw a few questions on SO that were similar to my own query, some with answers, but mostly unsolved or solved unsatisfactorily (from my point of view).

[image: Example question]

**What happened**:

I thought a'right, I may be able to build it myself. So I built a small library for doing just that, consuming Server-Sent Events with RxJava.

Then I remembered about those few questions that asked for such solutions, and dropped them a link to the GitHub repository, clearly stating that I made it. This was the result:

[image: Answer to that question]

**Question**:

1. Why was this answer removed? I can try to guess, but I still don't know. Downvoting and removing the answer doesn't tell me much.
2. I understand that "link-only" answers are discouraged. Does it still apply when the question is about finding a library?
3. What could I have done better?
4. Was the mod's action necessary?
5. Should the mod have handled it in another way?

Comment: At a quick glance you posted it four times (of which two are deleted). The answer amounts to nothing more than "I had the same problem and here's my library to solve it" - which in itself isn't an answer as it's nothing more than link only. I wouldn't be too surprised if the other posts also get deleted (although I won't do so right this moment). To avoid that - I'd suggest including exampes of how your library can be used in the context of the question so that it can be mostly a stand-alone answer. Of course, if the question itself is off-topic I wouldn't spend much time there doing so.

Comment: Closely related post on the central Meta: [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)

Comment: I've deleted the remaining copies of your answer; they really don't meet our standards for a proper answer.

Comment: @GhostlyMartijn thank you for the link, I will probably re-post some of those answers following these suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with [the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41638426/how-to-use-server-sent-events-sse-in-android-with-rxjava). It fits perfectly one of the standard off-topic reasons i.e.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

You should have flagged or voted the question for closure instead of answering it. Perhaps the mod should have simply closed the question by fiat but they are busy and simply responded to the flag on the answer without investigating the question that caused such an answer to be written.

The [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) has now resulted in the closure of the question.