# Where can I ask a question about locating an animated GIF?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

I have a question about where to find a decent programming GIF (keyword decent) that has a nice loop (where you can't tell its looping).

Would that be appropriate for Stack Overflow? Or is there another Stack Exchange site where I can ask this question?

Comment: The question of where to find an environment to ask the question is the same, but the subject of the question "photo/GIF" is different from "tool/library", this would result in different answers. This post shouldn't be treated as a duplicate.

Comment: Take for example the questions "what pizza would you like to eat?", and "what cake would you like to eat?", both questions are about what would you like to eat, but the question have different subjects so they're bond to have different results. Part of the answer given by Cody, " find a suitable animated GIF yourself by using Google's Advanced Image Search", wouldn't work for the question presented by gnat.

Comment: I'm sure Reddit has some sort of subreddit somewhere where people will gladly answer such a question. Just expect 99% of those gifs to be NSFW.

Comment: @johnsmith "duplicate" means "all answers to your questions are in the duplicate thread" and not "this precise and narrow variant of the problem is discussed in existing question". If you disagree with that - feel free to propose "feature-request" to change that (don't forget to include why it will make SE sites better and how existing discussions about duplicates did not cover that)

Answer (score 5):

That question would be off-topic for Stack Overflow, and pretty much everywhere else on the Stack Exchange network. We do not allow questions where you are asking for someone else to find an off-site resource. There is a close reason specifically for this:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

For programming questions, resource requests can often be rewritten so that they *are* acceptable, but that would not be possible in your case. There's no way to rewrite that into a form that would be on-topic.

You'll have to try other sites that have less rigorous standards for questions, like Yahoo! Answers, Reddit, or Quora.

Or, find a suitable animated GIF yourself by using Google's Advanced Image Search.