# Where would I ask this question: "Is Shopify easier than Wix.com?"

Tags: discussion

I am asking this question about asking a question here because I do not know where else to ask.

Comment: General comparison questions are almost universally off-topic because they are too vague and unclear.  You should read [Gorilla vs Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/) for some more background and details.  If you could craft such a comparison question that isn't a gorilla vs shark question then your resulting question would not be on-topic for Stack Overflow because it likely wouldn't be a programming question

Comment: Thanks, very informative. Should I delete this question?

Comment: I would like to take a moment to thank you for asking beforehand here on meta. The negative votes give you an insight on how the community feels about that Shopify vs wix question, but it's still great you got the presence of mind to ask here first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where? Not here.

However, in the exchanges vast topic set, you would probably find somewhere to ask such a question. No where will receive your question as it is currently written though.

What is the reason you are using Wix, or Shopify?

What is the primary concern you have with choosing Wix, or Shopify?

What defines "easier" in your situation?

Why didn't you just Google search and end up with [Wix vs Shopify comparison](https://websitebuildertips.com/wix-vs-shopify/?utm_campaign=ma_websitebuildertips_bi_wix_us%5E80474354859&experiment_id=1729774246%5E1t1%5E%2Bwix%20%2Bshopify%5Eb&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgom74OqD5gIVBL3sCh1ijAKSEAAYASAAEgIxAfD_BwE)?

Honestly, the largest issue any question you ask is going to be "was it well researched"? If it was, for the most part, it will end up in the right place if enough actual work was put into a good effort. Or at least something more than, "Hey, you know, I was thinking... wix. shopify. Now you go." because no one feels respected when we see that show up.

Perhaps you could make this question on topic at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Do note though, they have a strict set of rules for what is [on topic there](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> - A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
> - Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features

Make sure you review https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information before finalizing your question.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has enlightened me on a lot. I love asking questions and this is a fantastic explanation to help me ask better questions as well as not ask unnecessary questions that may be purely opinion based. I love the part about wasting peoples time as well as the part about elaborating more. The entire answer was helpful. Thanks again!