# What close reason was used to close this question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, post-notice

I am confused. Earlier I could easily determine the reasons, but looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59412027/1997232) ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59412027/timeline)) I am not able to figure it out.

> [image: closed post notice]

Which of those below off-topic reasons it was? I am curious and someone else may want to improve his SO-voting skills.

> [image: close voting pop-up]

Comment: It might have been three different off-topic close reasons

Comment: @Ctx Even if all 3 votes were the same it shows the same block. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395698/slow-booting-ubuntu-from-ssd-alongside-hdd)

Comment: @Machavity Hmm. On that question, I see the actual close reason that was chosen ("general computing/ask on Super User") displayed in that blue box.

Comment: @CodyGray Interesting. All I see in the reason area is `We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow. You can edit the question so it’s on-topic for Stack Overflow.`

Comment: @Machavity Yeah, I guess that's what I'm referring to. It doesn't say "Super User" anymore, which I actually see as a good thing. One of the big issues I had with using that particular off-topic sub-reason is that I didn't want to make it sound like I was recommending the person go ask the question on Super User.

Comment: @CodyGray While I can see your point, if the question was bad for even SU I would pick another close reason. There are times we can and should recommend other sites where the subject is on-topic (SO does not do a good job on this overall, even before the recent changes). It's just kinda silly to have one that implies that the user will be directed there when it no longer does that

Answer (score 28):

A "recommend closure" flag was raised suggesting that the question was opinion-based. [John_ReinstateMonica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john-reinstatemonica) agreed with that flag, and submitted a close vote on the same basis:

> Opinion based → Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Following that, [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) and [Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) voted to close as off-topic because it was asking for a recommendation:

> Off-topic → Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Since the majority voted to close the question as "off-topic", the system considered it closed on that basis. That is the reason that got officially recorded in the history, and is what you see in [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59412027/timeline).

Apparently, [the new post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide) are no longer distinguishing between the "off-topic" closure reasons in the notices. This is, in my opinion, a *major* misfeature. It was already confusing enough to group things like "no minimal, reproducible example" and "typo or not useful to others" underneath the "off-topic" category. But at least before, there was some explanatory text describing the actual reason for the closure. Now, there's just boilerplate suggesting that it is off-topic, which is absurd on its face, since these questions are clearly about programming. The off-topic closure only makes sense to people who are already experts on the nuanced scope of Stack Overflow, and this population of users has almost no overlap with the population of users whom we are trying to educate with the notices.

Comment: The new post notices do distinguish between all off-topic closure reasons, except "resource request" and custom reasons. Resource requests and custom reasons are only identified as "off-topic". I submitted a bug report about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337914/271271), but it was marked as [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. However, these distinctions are only shown to the OP and users who can vote to close. I fully agree that this makes it *far* less understandable why a question was closed to users with < 3k rep who are not the OP. That's really bad, IMO.

Comment: Is the information you found on the sub-reasons chosen publicly available somewhere, or is only available to mods? (I tried `https://stackoverflow.com/flags/questions/59412027/close/popup`, but it doesn't work)

Comment: *are no longer distinguishing between the "off-topic" closure reasons in the notices* ... they do (for everybody that can vote, and the OP, in most cases) ?

Answer (score 13):

This is a major bug resulting from the new post notices, which hasn't been fixed to this day. The off-topic close reasons are not always displayed correctly.

Here are just some possible variants:

- [Variable types in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906889/variable-types-in-php) (closed as: "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" and "lacks minimal understanding")
  [image]
- [The Insert Query is inserting two rows when it should only insert one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347101/the-insert-query-is-inserting-two-rows-when-it-should-only-insert-one) (closed as: no MRE/MCVE)
  [image]
- [Why this query is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037273/why-this-query-is-not-working) (closed as: lacks minimal understanding)
  [image]
- [Check if IP is banned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044642/check-if-ip-is-banned) (closed as: typo / no repo)
  [image]
- [Is there a command to batch change time zones of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59410205/is-there-a-command-to-batch-change-time-zones-of-files) (closed as: general computing)
  [image]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364706/how-do-i-start-aws-training-videos (closed as: Custom reason: Not a programming question)
  [image]
- [What is a better file copy alternative than the Windows default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329/what-is-a-better-file-copy-alternative-than-the-windows-default) (Locked for Historical significance)
  [image]

As you can see, there is not much consistency. Sometimes the reason is displayed; sometimes it is not. Sometimes it says to "Edit" the post; other times it says to "Update".

I often struggle to understand what the actual closure reason is, and it might take me sometimes reading through the question, all the answers, and all the comments to figure out why it was closed as off-topic. It would be nice if this information was clearly visible in the closure banner.

Comment: I agree that what is displayed is far less easy to understand at a glance than what it used to be. However, the notices are differentiated for all current, and old, off-topic reasons which I've seen, except "resource request" and custom reasons. Resource requests and custom reasons are both grouped just under "off-topic" with no differentiation between the text. However, the differences between reasons are only shown to the OP and users with >=3k rep. There's no difference in the displayed text between off-topic reasons, as shown to users <3k rep.