# What about creating a section for recommendations of libraries and book?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

These kind of question come back recurrently, and get closed at some point, but still get strong scores ie., it's useful to people.

eg., [How to easily draw graphs in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479768/how-to-easily-draw-graphs-in-wpf)

score 33, Viewed 58k times

That potential section would be in SO, but outside the usual Q/A.

Comment: [Most proposals for recommenation sites failed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s/268486)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: 1. It goes against everything that has made this site a success, and 2. Recommendation sites are already available for your use

Comment: The best part of that question is that the top answer is listing libraries the OP wasn't looking for, basically because their question was missing exact requirements. That part is at least covered by SoftwareRecs.se in their quality guidance.

Answer (score 9):

That wouldn't solve the fundamental problem: these questions attract spam and opinionated answers. Why is one answer suggesting a book or tutorial any better or worse than another one? How would you decide? Just based on your personal preferences? This would make voting and moderation difficult or impossible.